# What's the closest thing to Haskell GADTs and typeclasses in F#?

Tags: f#, typeclass, gadt

F# is an ML with OOP. What's the closest it comes to Haskell generalized algebraic data types and typeclasses?

Answer (score 19):

The answer depends on what problem are you trying to solve. F# does not have typeclasses and GADTs, so there is no direct mapping. However, F# has various mechanisms that you would use to solve problems that you typically solve in Haskell using GADTs and typeclasses:

- If you want to represent object structures and be able to add new concrete implementations with different behaviour, then you can often use standard OO and interfaces.
- If you want to write generic numeric code, you can use static member constraints ([here is an example](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-generic-numeric.aspx)), which is probably *technically* the closest mechanism to type classes.
- If you want to write more advanced generic code (like universal printer or parser) then you can often use the [powerful F# runtime reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353491.aspx) capabilities.
- If you need to parameterize code by a set of functions (that perform various sub-operations required by the code) then you can pass around an implementation of an interface as @pad shows.

There is also a way to [emulate Haskell type classes in F#](http://code.google.com/p/fsharp-typeclasses/), but this is usually not an idiomatic F# solution, because the F# programming style differs from the Haskell style in a number of ways. One fairly standard use of this is defining overloaded operators though (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971965/overloaded-inline-operators-in-f)).

*At the meta-level, asking what is an equivalent to a feature X in aother language often leads to a confused discussion, because X might be used to solve problems A, B, C in one language while another language may provide different features to solve the same problems (or some of the problems may not exist at all).*

Answer (score 7):

In F#, you often use [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233207.aspx) and [inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233225.aspx) for these purposes.

For examples' sake, here is a simple typeclass using interfaces and [object expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233237.aspx):

```
/// Typeclass
type MathOps<'T> =
    abstract member Add : 'T -> 'T -> 'T
    abstract member Mul : 'T -> 'T -> 'T

/// An instance for int
let mathInt = 
    { new MathOps<int> with
       member __.Add x y = x + y
       member __.Mul x y = x * y }

/// An instance for float
let mathFloat = 
    { new MathOps<float> with
       member __.Add x y = x + y
       member __.Mul x y = x * y }

let XtimesYplusZ (ops: MathOps<'T>) x y z =
    ops.Add (ops.Mul x y) z

printfn "%d" (XtimesYplusZ mathInt 3 4 1)
printfn "%f" (XtimesYplusZ mathFloat 3.0 4.0 1.0)
```

It may not look very beautiful, but it's F#-ish way to do it. For a more Haskell-like solution which uses a dictionary-of-operations, you can have a look at [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664258/alternative-to-typeclasses).

Comment: This is a misleading example, because for numerical code you can just write `let inline XtimesYplusZ x y z = (x * y) + z` and `XtimesYplusZ 3 4 1` and `XtimesYplusZ 3.0 4.0 1.0` will work. But of course, in a different scenario, code based on the style you're demonstrating would be a good way to model this kind of parameterization by operations. I guess that's what I mean by saying that there are different approaches for different problems solved by type classes in Haskell.

Comment: Yes, I struggled to find a good example. What I would like to demonstrate is the coding style only; it isn't about numerical code.

Comment: Didn't get it. You're just using generics.

Comment: @LeoCavalcante, here's a Haskell article explaining the idea: http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/05/scrap-your-type-classes.html

Basically you can take the typeclass-using signature (Monad m) => [m a] -> m [a] and transform it into a regular value signature MonadWitness m -> [m a] -> m [a], and bypass type-level programming entirely, as long as you're willing to explicitly pass in the witness.