# Avoiding Java Type Erasure

Tags: java, templates, generics, generic-programming, type-erasure

Is there a way one could avoid type erasure and get access to a type parameter?

```
public class Foo<T extends Enum<?> & Bar> {
    public Foo() {
        // access the template class here?
        // i.e. :
        baz(T.class); // obviously doesn't work
    }

    private void baz(Class<T> qux) { 
        // do stuff like
        T[] constants = qux.getEnumConstants();
        ...
    } 
}
```

I need to know about `T`, and do things with it. Is it possible, and if so, how can it be done *without* passing in the class in the constructor or anywhere besides the parameter?

**EDIT:** The main purpose of this question is to find out if there is *any practical way* around type erasure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFACT, there is *no* practical way around type erasure because you can't ask for something which the runtime doesn't have access to. Assuming of course you agree that sub-classing generic classes for each enum which implements `Bar` interface is a practical work around.

```
enum Test implements Bar {
    ONE, TWO
}

class Foo<T> extends FooAbstract<Test> {
    public Foo() {
        ParameterizedType genericSuperclass =
                (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        baz((Class<T>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
    }

    private void baz(Class<T> qux) {
        T[] constants = qux.getEnumConstants();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(constants)); // print [ONE, TWO]
    }
}

interface Bar {
}

class FooAbstract<T extends Enum<?> & Bar> {
}
```

Comment: +1 Yep - This is another reflection-based alternative if you prefer subclassing to passing the `Class` object.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing/able to hand a class token to the constructor:

```
public Foo(Class<T> clazz) {
    baz(clazz);
}

private void baz(Class<T> qux) {
    // ...
}
```

That way, you can produce objects of type T with Class.newInstance(), attempt to cast arbitrary objects to T using Class.cast(), etc.

What do you intend to do in baz()?

Comment: Let's say it asks the given class for a list of values and makes use of those values. Passing in the class is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

As pholser points out in his answer, the only way to achieve this is by passing in the `Class` object representing the type `T`.  It's because of [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) that something like `T.class` isn't possible because `T` is erased before runtime.

You seem resistant against passing in the `Class` object, but it's the only way to use the method [`getEnumConstants()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29). Here is a self contained example:

```
public class Foo<T extends Enum<?> & Bar> {

   final Class<T> clazz;

   public Foo(Class<T> clazz) {

      this.clazz = clazz;
   }

   public void baz() {

      T[] constants = clazz.getEnumConstants();

      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(constants));
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       new Foo<MyEnum>(MyEnum.class).baz(); //prints "[A, B, C, D]"
   }
}

public interface Bar { }

public enum MyEnum implements Bar { A, B, C, D; }
```

Comment: So there's absolutely no way for me to get around the Type Erasure and figure out the class passed in as `T`? The idea of this thread is to find out if there is any way around type erasure.

Comment: @Chris - Reflection is the only workaround to type erasure in Java. But you're put at no more disadvantage from what you have by passing in the `Class` object, though it's annoying and looks redundant at compile time. Notice that you're already relying on reflection by using `Class#getEnumConstants()`. The only alternative is a complete redesign that removes your dependence on that method.

Answer (score 1):

Use a super type token as proposed by Neil Gafter and used by libraries like guice for this purpose.

See http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html for the original description and I've check out the guice source for CA radio life working implementation.

there is another q which has an answer with worked example inline here [How can I pass a Class as parameter and return a generic collection in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397160/how-can-i-pass-a-class-as-parameter-and-return-a-generic-collection-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you can use a workaround suggested by Richard Gomes.
When creating instances of anonymous classes, the type parameter class info is available.

```
class A<T>
{
    A()
    {
        java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType)  (this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass());
        System.out.println(parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
    }
}

public class Example {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     A<String> anonymous = new A<String>() {};  // prints java.lang.String
}
}
```

Note that multiple instances created this way will be of different anonymous classes, and if that's a problem you might want a class A_String_Factory with a createNew() function based on clone to replace the calls to new.