# Retrieve the classes used within an instance of a Generic Type using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Suppose to have a type `Pair<K,V>` declared in your package. Given an object instance of:

```
 Pair<Integer, Integer> obj = new Pair<>(1,23);
```

I want to retrieve the type arguments `Integer` and `Integer` to which `K` and `V` are respectively associated. By the way, it seems to be that using Java standard reflection I cannot access to the actual class with the instances within Java.

```
 TypeVariable<? extends Class<?>>[] parameters = obj.getClass().getTypeParameters();
```

I did not manage to extract such desired information  using such parameters. I start to wonder, maybe the type information is kept only at compile time, while at run time the actual type parameter information is removed.

Comment: So, you just want the type of the type argument in the  of the Pair object which in your example `Integer` ?

Comment: Exactely. I just manage to retrieve K and V from the type parameters, but I do not get the actual classes which are associated to such paramteres.

Comment: Is is always a primitive-like type (i.e. `Integer`, `String` ..etc) or it could be of an Object Type (e.g. `Class Person` )?

Comment: It could be even an Object Type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime?rq=1

Comment: No. As I said in my post, I only want to use reflection. Plus, the classes could even come from external libraries over which I have no control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have an instance, as you exemplified: `Pair<Integer, Integer> pair = new Pair<>(1,23)`, there's no way to get the static generic types as that information is lost in runtime.

If, on the other hand, `Pair<Integer, String>` was the type of a field, method return type, the type of a method parameter, or if the generic type arguments came from the superclass, it would be possible to extract the static generic types.

Check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038691/how-dwr-cast-incoming-data-and-evade-type-erasure/40202885#40202885) for examples on extracting generic types in these cases.

Short of that, you can only check the dynamic types of the values in runtime, as explained by [Yahya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43700981/294657).

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this answer:

```
public static String[] getArgumentType(Object obj){
    String[] type = new String[2];
    type[0]=((Pair<?, ?>) obj).getKey().getClass().getName().replace("java.lang.", "");
    type[1]=((Pair<?, ?>) obj).getValue().getClass().getName().replace("java.lang.", "");
    return type;
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pair<String,Integer> obj = new Pair<String,Integer>("", 2);
    String[] type = getArgumentType(obj);
    System.out.println(type[0] + ", " + type[1]);
    Pair<Integer,Integer> obj1 = new Pair<Integer,Integer>(1, 2);
    type = getArgumentType(obj1);
    System.out.println(type[0] + ", " + type[1]);
    Pair<Double,Float> obj2 = new Pair<Double,Float>(1.1, 2.2f);
    type = getArgumentType(obj2);
    System.out.println(type[0] + ", " + type[1]);
    Pair<Person,Object> obj3 = new Pair<Person,Object>(new Person(), new Object());
    type = getArgumentType(obj3);
    System.out.println(type[0] + ", " + type[1]);
}
```

**The Output:**

```
String, Integer
Integer, Integer
Double, Float
Person, Object
```

Comment: Since in my context-application I do not need to have the actual class is ok… but, is there no way to get the same result by using the reflection, that is more clean than parsing a string?

Comment: Plus, Pair is just an example, and I could even have different and other types of classes to which I do not know the association between the type parameter and the getter.