# Is there any opportunity to use Class <?, ?> for my projects?

Tags: java, generics, methods

I hava some problems with my code. 
First of all I have an interface:

```
public interface Generator <T, R> {
    public T next (R x);
}
```

Then, I have created the class "DemoClass"

```
public class DemoClass {
    private int id;

    public DemoClass (int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And... Generic Class as well

```
public class GenericClass implements Generator <DemoClass, Integer> {
    public DemoClass next(Integer x) {
        return new DemoClass (x);
    }
}
```

After, I have created Main Class and a generic static method that containts a method like Class . I would like to know, is there any opportunity to use such construction like Class ???
My MainClass

```
import java.util.*;

public class MainClass {
    private static Random rand = new Random ();

    public static <T> T [] arr (T [] a, Class <?> typeToken){
        try{
            Generator <?, ?> gen = (Generator <?, ?>)typeToken.newInstance(); // How can I pass two paramets to Generator <?, ?>???
            for (int i=0; i!=a.length; i++){
                a[i] = (T) gen.next(rand.nextInt(100)); // This  line does not work!
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException (e);
        }
        return a;
}

    public static void main (String [] args){
        DemoClass [] myarr = arr (new DemoClass[10], GenericClass.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make that line work, you could do this:

```
public static <T> T[] arr(T[] a, Class<? extends Generator<T, Integer>> typeToken) {
    try {
        Generator<T, Integer> gen = typeToken.newInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i != a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = gen.next(rand.nextInt(100));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Basically, the bound on `Class` makes it so that what is returned by `newInstance` is a `Generator<T, Integer>`.

> How can I pass two paramets to Generator ???

There is no need to pass any type parameters. Since Java generics use erasure, the concrete generic type arguments are not needed at runtime.

---

If you are using Java 8, I would suggest using a `Supplier` instead of a `Class`, since it allows you to create an instance without having to deal with the exceptions:

```
public static <T> T[] arr(T[] a, Supplier<? extends Generator<T, Integer>> typeToken) {
    Generator<T, Integer> gen = typeToken.get();
    for (int i = 0; i != a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = gen.next(rand.nextInt(100));
    }
    return a;
}
```

...

```
// passing reference to constructor of GenericClass
DemoClass[] myarr = arr(new DemoClass[10], GenericClass::new);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score -1):

No.

Generics work at compile time only. At runtime, all of the instances of class are exactly the same, the information of the parametrized types gone.

This is known as **type erasure** and it was designed that way to ensure that Java 1.4 binaries were compatible with Java 5 VM.

You can get a lot of info about this by searching "type erasure java" in the search box; for example [Avoiding Java Type Erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452893/avoiding-java-type-erasure)