# Passing a Class for object serialization to xml

Tags: java, class

After reading both

[How can I pass a Class as parameter and return a generic collection in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397160/how-can-i-pass-a-class-as-parameter-and-return-a-generic-collection-in-java)

and

[How do I pass a class as a parameter in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872978/how-do-i-pass-class-as-a-parameter-in-java)

I am unsure how I would pass a JibX generated class as a parameter to a method that serializes the object.

I would like to accomplish something like the following.

```
protected static String SerializeObject( Class clazz , Object request)
{
    String message = null;

    try
    {
      IBindingFactory lBindingFactory = BindingDirectory.getFactory(
              clazz.class);
      IMarshallingContext lContext = lBindingFactory.
              createMarshallingContext();
      ByteArrayOutputStream lOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      lContext.marshalDocument(request, "UTF-8", null,
              lOutputStream);
      message = new String(lOutputStream.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (JiBXException lEx)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException("Problems generating XML, " +
            "underlying problem is " +  lEx.getMessage(), lEx);
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException lEx)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException("Problems generating XML in specified" +
              "encoding, underlying problem is " + lEx.getMessage(), lEx);
    }
    return message;
}
```

Where the class is only used to define what the BindingDirectory is using to serialize the object into.

Comment: Just wanted to point out the alternative of JAXB + annotations.

Comment: For this project I am not using JAXB for a few reasons related to other questions I have asked in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be better to avoid attempting to pass the class at all. I can achieve the same affect by passing the IBindingFactory and adding a bit of code to the caller.

The result would end up like this.

```
protected static String SerializeObject( IBindingFactory lBindingFactory,
        Object request)
{
    String message = null;

    try
    {
      IMarshallingContext lContext = lBindingFactory.
              createMarshallingContext();
      ByteArrayOutputStream lOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      lContext.marshalDocument(request, "UTF-8", null,
              lOutputStream);
      message = new String(lOutputStream.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (JiBXException lEx)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException("Problems generating XML, " +
            "underlying problem is " +  lEx.getMessage(), lEx);
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException lEx)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException("Problems generating XML in specified" +
              "encoding, underlying problem is " + lEx.getMessage(), lEx);
    }
    return message;
}
```