# Doclet- Get generics of a list

Tags: java, generics, javadoc

I am writing a doclet extending com.sun.javadoc.Doclet.

When i want want to document an ArrayList as a field of a method i want to get the type of the generic (e.g. when documenting an `ArrayList<String>` I want to get the information that this is a list containing Strings).

I am only able to get the information, that this is a ArrayList. Even when calling

```
ParameterizedType paramType = fieldType.asParameterizedType();
```

I am only getting *java.util.ArrayList* and not the type of the generic.

Does someone know how to get the generic type of the list?

Here is the example code:

```
FieldDoc[] fields = classDoc.fields();
for (int k = 0; k < fields.length; k++) {
    Type fieldType = fields[k].type();
    if (fieldType.asParameterizedType() != null) {
        ParameterizedType paramType = fieldType.asParameterizedType();
        String qualiName = paramType.qualifiedTypeName(); // this equals "java.util.ArrayList"
        fieldType.asParameterizedType().toString(); // this equals "java.util.ArrayList"
        fieldType.asParameterizedType().typeName(); // this equals "ArrayList"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is *field of a method*? A method parameter?

Answer (score 24):

I was running into generics being lost on types while writing a custom doclet under Java 1.6.  I was able to fix it by adding the method below to my doclet.

```
   /**
    * NOTE: Without this method present and returning LanguageVersion.JAVA_1_5,
    *       Javadoc will not process generics because it assumes LanguageVersion.JAVA_1_1
    * @return language version (hard coded to LanguageVersion.JAVA_1_5)
    */
   public static LanguageVersion languageVersion() {
      return LanguageVersion.JAVA_1_5;
   }
```

Comment: You made my day. It took me 2 month to find this piece of information in the world wide web.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the output is `java.util.ArrayList<String>` and you don't see the `<String>` part since your browser interprets it as an unknown HTML tag?

You will have to escape the `<` for HTML output.

If this is not the problem, show enough code so we can reproduce the problem.

---

After seeing your example, I could reproduce it with this doclet:

```
package de.fencing_game.paul.examples.doclet;

import com.sun.javadoc.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A test doclet to see how generic fields work.
 *
 * Inspired by the question <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/5731619/600500">Doclet- Get generics of a list</a> on Stackoverflow.
 */
public class GenericTestDoclet<Y> extends Doclet {

    public ArrayList<? extends Y> stringList;

    /**
     * Erstellt ein(e(n)) neu(e(n)) <code>GenericTestDoclet</code>.
     *
     */
    public GenericTestDoclet() {

    }


    public ArrayList<? extends Y> getList() {
        return stringList;
    }

    public void printType(Type fieldType, DocErrorReporter err) {
        err.printNotice("type: " + fieldType);
        if (fieldType.asParameterizedType() != null) {
            ParameterizedType paramType = fieldType.asParameterizedType();
            err.printNotice("paramType:" + paramType);
            String qualiName = paramType.qualifiedTypeName();
            err.printNotice("qualiName: " + qualiName);

            String typeName = fieldType.asParameterizedType().typeName();
            err.printNotice("typeName: " + typeName);

            Type[] parameters = paramType.typeArguments();
            err.printNotice("parameters.length: " + parameters.length);
            for(Type p : parameters) {
                err.printNotice("param: " + p);
            }
        }
        err.printNotice("");
    }


    public void listFields(ClassDoc classDoc, DocErrorReporter err) {
        FieldDoc[] fields = classDoc.fields();
        for (int k = 0; k < fields.length; k++) {
            err.printNotice("field: " + fields[k]);
            Type fieldType = fields[k].type();
            printType(fieldType, err);
        }
    }


    public void listMethods(ClassDoc classDoc, DocErrorReporter err) {
        MethodDoc[] methods = classDoc.methods();
        for (int k = 0; k < methods.length; k++) {
            err.printNotice("method: " + methods[k]);
            Type returnType = methods[k].returnType();
            printType(returnType, err);
        }
    }



    /**
     * The entry point of the doclet.
     * @return true if all the included elements have enough documentation,
     *   false if some documentation is missing.
     */
    public static boolean start(RootDoc root) {
        GenericTestDoclet<?> d = new GenericTestDoclet<Integer>();
        for(ClassDoc clazz : root.classes()) {
            d.listFields(clazz, root);
            d.listMethods(clazz, root);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The output, if applied on itself:

```
field: de.fencing_game.paul.examples.doclet.GenericTestDoclet.stringList
type: java.util.ArrayList
paramType:java.util.ArrayList
qualiName: java.util.ArrayList
typeName: ArrayList
parameters.length: 0

method: de.fencing_game.paul.examples.doclet.GenericTestDoclet.getList()
type: java.util.ArrayList
paramType:java.util.ArrayList
qualiName: java.util.ArrayList
typeName: ArrayList
parameters.length: 0

[more methods omitted]
```

It shows that also return types seem to be parameterless here.

I wanted to say that I already used this method to [print recursively a type name](https://github.com/ePaul/ltxdoclet/blob/master/src/de/dclj/paul/ltxdoclet/LaTeXWriter.java#L274), but it shows that my LaTeX-Doclet actually is not even using the recursive method I created (instead the types are [printed from the compiler tree of the type](https://github.com/ePaul/ltxdoclet/blob/master/src/de/dclj/paul/ltxdoclet/PrettyPrinter.java#L1524)).

But somehow this has to be possible, since somehow the Standard Doclet [manges to create the right output](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/DragGestureRecognizer.html#events).

Comment: I do not think, that the missing escape of `<` is the problem. Currently i am debugging the documentation tool in eclipse.
To give you some more code:
I am iterating through an array of fieldDoc[] elements and check if it is a parameterized type (see following post).

Does someone know a solution?

I think there must be a way to document the generic type of a list....

Comment: Here some code:
`FieldDoc[] fields = classDoc.fields();
 for (int k = 0; k < fields.length; k++) {
  Type fieldType = fields[k].type();
  if (fieldType.asParameterizedType() != null) {
   ParameterizedType paramType = fieldType.asParameterizedType();
   String qualiName = paramType.qualifiedTypeName(); // this equals "java.util.ArrayList"
   fieldType.asParameterizedType().toString();  // this equals "java.util.ArrayList"
   fieldType.asParameterizedType().typeName();  // this equals "ArrayList"
  }
 }`

Comment: I added your code to the question, it is a lot easier to read this way (and less likely to be missed).

Answer (score 1):

After enabling Java 1.5 mode with Trex's answer, you can access the generic types of `fieldType` using

```
Type[] typeArguments = fieldType.asParameterizedType().typeArguments()
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming the ArrayList is a member field of your class, it looks like the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list) will provide what you need.

A snippet of the code from that answer shows the general idea (but take a look at that question/answer):

```
Field stringListField = Test.class.getDeclaredField("stringList");
ParameterizedType stringListType = (ParameterizedType) stringListField.getGenericType();
Class<?> stringListClass = (Class<?>) stringListType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
System.out.println(stringListClass); // class java.lang.String.
```

Comment: again, doclets operate on the source, not the compiled code. Reflection is not the way to go