# Determine generic arguments of List<>

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I'm using reflection to walk the field members of a class and I need to know for List<> subclasses, what the generic type parameters are.

Given a field that has a type that is a subclass of List, how can I tell in a generic way what the type parameters of List<> are?

For example:

```
class X<T> {
   List<String> x1; // String
   ArrayList<String> x2; // String
   SubclassOfArrayListString x3; // String
   List<?> x4; // error
   List<T> x5; // error
}

class SubclassOfArrayListString extends ArrayList<String> {
   // ...
}
```

NOTE: I added `<T>` to X above to illustrate that there might be cases where there isn't a correct answer - it has nothing to do with the problem, except being something to consider when answering.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get generic type of java.util.List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list)

Comment: So do you want something like this? x1 -> [class java.lang.String], x2 -> [class java.lang.String], x3: class SubclassOfArrayListString, x4 -> [?] (WildcardType), x5 -> [T] (TypeVariable)

Comment: Philipp: x3->String, x4/x5 are "undefined", so as long as I can determine that they have no full type yet, that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't because generic type information is lost on compilation **(*)**. That's also the reason you cannot create an array of some generic type `T` at runtime.

At runtime, every `List<T>`is again a raw type `List` -- you could even add an `Integer` to something declared  as `List<String>`, generics won't and can't prevent that [Edit: using unchecked casts or a widening cast to a raw type; this will result in (suppressable) compiler warnings but no errors].

**(*)** Edit: I learned some new and stand corrected, certain type parameters (implementors of [GenericDeclaration](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/GenericDeclaration.html) like `Class`, `Constructor`, `Field` and the return, parameter and exception types of `Method`) will be retained in the byte code and can be accessed at runtime using [Field.getGenericType()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType%28%29) and similar accessors.

Comment: Sorry, that's not actually true for generic types. f.getGenericType() returns the parameterized type, ie: java.util.List<java.lang.String>

Comment: @Saher Yes, not directly but using an unchecked cast or widening cast to a raw type `List` (a mistake easily made) you could in fact add anything to any `Collection` without the compiler preventing it -- it would only warn and even that can be suppressed.

Comment: @slipheed I didn't know that. But couldn't you then just call `getGenericType()` on the `Field`s of the class you reflect on?

Comment: @Philipp, yeah, but I'm not sure what the right technique is to walk up the chain of supertypes. I was hoping this had been solved before.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class X<T extends List> {
  T field;
}
```

Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Read this tutorial about Generics : [Generics Tutorial](http://stellar.mit.edu/S/course/6/sp11/6.005/courseMaterial/topics/topic2/studyMaterial/generics-tutorial/generics-tutorial.pdf). This should clear things up.

This pdf has also good examples at the end of the wildcard usage as well as the extends ans super keywords. [PDF Doc](http://stellar.mit.edu/S/course/6/sp11/6.005/courseMaterial/topics/topic2/lectureNotes/Generics-spring11/Generics-spring11.pdf)

Basically, Use `Container<? extends A>` when you want to read from the container
Use `Container<? super A>` when you want to write to the container.