# How to Get class of Elements that List Contains?

Tags: java, class, list

I have a list like that:

```
private List<T> myList = new ArrayList<T>();
```

I want to get the .class of T. How can I do that?

I mean as like:

```
myList.getClass()
```

**EDIT:**
I tried that:

```
 Field genericField = Wrapper.class.getDeclaredField("myList");
 ParameterizedType genericType = (ParameterizedType) genericField.getGenericType();
 Class<?> genericClass = (Class<?>) genericType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

and when I debug it

> genericType

has a value of:

> java.util.List

so I think that this is certainly different issue from that question: [Get generic type of java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list) because of  if you declare a class with `T` and assign something to `T` later at another method, class that `T` holds disappear.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list

Comment: @oers I think this question differs from you suggest. Because I use `T` and it makes everything different.

Comment: @kamaci: it's not clear from your question whether T is supposed to be a placeholder for a concrete class or a type paramter of the enclosing class. In the latter case, the answers that say it's impossible are actually correct.

Comment: @kamaci: Ah, yes it is different. (It would be good to provide the broader code context.) And no, there's no way to do that.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt I tried to explain it. `T` is a placeholder here and I instantiate my class so `T` holds something but after that I think that it disappear.

Comment: @kamaci: yes that information is erased, there is no way to get it without changing the code specifically to preserve it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't because of type erasure.
The generic type is not known at runtime (it's 'erased'), it's only used at compile time.

This is a major difference between java generics and c# generics for example.

Answer (score 8):

Why do you need to know this?  Perhaps this will do what you need

```
// must be at least one element (and all elements are the same)
Class elementType = myList.get(0).getClass();
```

---

The only way to do this is to either

- store the type in a field and add a getter method for this.

like

```
private final Class<T> type;
private final List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

public Class<T> getType() { return type; }
```

- use getGenericType() on the actual field, assuming the parameter type is NOT generic.
- use a sub class with a specific type.

like

```
List list = new ArrayList<Integer>() { }; // create a specific sub-class
final Class<? extends List> listClass = list.getClass();
final ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) listClass.getGenericSuperclass();
Class elementType = (Class) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

This has the dis-advantage that you could end up creating lots of anonymous classes and potential confusion with things like `ArrayList.class != list.getClass()` however `list instanceof ArrayList`

Comment: You could create an anonymous sub-type of the class which contains this field.

Comment: @kamaci: the first one does, but it would require your surrounding class to take a `Class<T>` parameter in its constructor.

Comment: type variable should be initialized?

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt I dont want to send parameter to constructor of Wrapper class because of my limitations

Comment: As MichaelBorgwardt points out, it has to be set in the constructor.

Comment: @kamaci, Can you use the `Wrapper<Integer> wrap = new Wrapper<Integer>() { };` approach?

Comment: @PeterLawrey thanks for answer. Just to be sure: I can't send a parapeter to constructor however I can change the code inside the constructor. So does it mean that I will not be able to do it because of I can't send parameter?

Comment: @kamaci, Not unless you create a sub-class as I suggested (twice)

Comment: @PeterLawrey sorry but couldn't understand what you mean. I didn't understand how to initialize that type variable.

Comment: @kamaci, If you use a sub-class, there is no type variable. However, you have to change all the callers, which I suspect you can't do (or you would just add a parameter)

Answer (score 3):

This is only possible if the list, as implied in your example, is a field AND the type parameter is concrete rather than itself being a type parameter of the enclosing class (which seems to be the case in your example), and you can only get the declared type parameter for the field via reflection:

```
Field listField = Test.class.getDeclaredField("myList");
ParameterizedType listType= (ParameterizedType) listField.getGenericType();
Class contentClass = (Class) listType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Not sure if this is entirely correct, but you get the idea - it's rather complex because type parameters can be bounded and wildcards.

Comment: This won't actually work if the type is `T` as it is above. It will only work if the parameter type is an actual class like `List<Integer>`

Comment: @PeterLawrey you got the point. It doesn't work because of `T`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. That information is not available at runtime. If your list isn't empty you might be able to get away with checking the class of the first element.

Comment: The information actually *is* available at runtime since the private keyword indicates that it's a field.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt, The parameter type is `T` which you cannot cast to a `Class`