# Generic type of local variable at runtime

Tags: java, generics, reflection, type-erasure

Is there a way in Java to reflect a generic type of a local variable? I know you can do that with a field - [Get generic type of java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list). Any idea how to solve, for instance:

```
public void foo(List<String> s){
  //reflect s somehow to get String
}
```

Or even more general:

```
public void foo<T>(List<T> s){
  //reflect s somehow to get T
}
```

Comment: what are you exactly want to accomplish with s? can you show me a short example (pseudo code doesn't matter)

Comment: With generics you could do something like public void foo<T extends Object> T> (List<T> s), if that's what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html) is nice tutorial that shows how and when you can read generic types using reflection. For example to get String from your firs `foo` method

```
public void foo(List<String> s) {
    // ..
}
```

you can use this code

```
class MyClass {

    public static void foo(List<String> s) {
        // ..
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method method = MyClass.class.getMethod("foo", List.class);

        Type[] genericParameterTypes = method.getGenericParameterTypes();

        for (Type genericParameterType : genericParameterTypes) {
            if (genericParameterType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                ParameterizedType aType = (ParameterizedType) genericParameterType;
                Type[] parameterArgTypes = aType.getActualTypeArguments();
                for (Type parameterArgType : parameterArgTypes) {
                    Class parameterArgClass = (Class) parameterArgType;
                    System.out.println("parameterArgClass = "
                            + parameterArgClass);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output: **parameterArgClass = class java.lang.String**

It was possible because your explicitly declared in source code that List can contains only Strings. However in case

```
public <T> void foo2(List<T> s){
      //reflect s somehow to get T
}
```

T can be anything so because of type erasure it is impossible to retrieve info about precise T class.

Answer (score 7):

**No**. Due to Java's [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), all generics are stripped during the compile process.

You can however use `instanceOf` or `getClass` on elements in the list to see if they match a specific type.

Comment: But you can still do the same thing on the field, so the info is stored somewhere...

Comment: Fields are different because their exact generic type is stored in the class file statically.  Johan is correct: you _cannot_ do this.