# How to check if a generic type implements a specific type of generic interface in java?

Tags: java, generics, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generic type of local variable at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798951/generic-type-of-local-variable-at-runtime)

I'm new to Java generics, and coming from a .NET world, I'm used to being able to write a method like this:

```
public void genericMethod<T>(T genericObject)
{
    if (genericObject is IList<String>)
    {
        //Do something...
    }            
}
```

The method accepts an object of a generic type, and checks whether that object implements a *specific* version of the generic interface `IList<>`, in this case, `IList<String>`.

Now, in Java, I'm able to do this:

```
public <T> void genericMethod(T genericObject)
{
    if (genericObject instanceof Set<?>)
    {
       //Do something...
    }
}
```

**BUT**

Java does *not* let me do `if (genericObject instanceof Set<String>)`

From what I know, because of type erasure, normally in Java this would be taken care of by a class object, and we would do something like the following:

```
public <T> void genericMethod(T genericObject)
{
    Class<OurTestingType> testClass = OurTestingType.class;
    if (genericObject.getClass() == testClass)
    {
       //Do something...
    }
}
```

but since the type I'm checking for is a generic interface, you can't do this:

`Class<Set<String>> testClass = Set<String>.class`

So, how, in Java, do I check if a generic object implements the specific type of `Set<String>`?

Comment: Generics are a compile time feature so you cannot simply get the specific generic type used at runtime. You could infer it from the contents or an additional argument e.g. `Class<T> tClass`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Java implements erasure, so there's no way to tell on runtime if `genericObject` is an instance of `Set<String>` or not. The only way to guarantee this is to use bounds on your generics, or check all elements in the set.

### Compile-time Generic Bounds

Using bounds checking, which will be checked at compile-time:

```
public <T extends SomeInterface> void genericMethod(Set<? extends T> tSet) {
    // Do something with tSet here
}
```

### Java 8

We can use streams in Java 8 to do this natively in a single line:

```
public <T> void genericMethod(T t) {
    if (t instanceof Set<?>) {
        Set<?> set = (Set<?>) t;
        if (set.stream().allMatch(String.class:isInstance)) {
            Set<String> strs = (Set<String>) set;
            // Do something with strs here
        }
    }
}
```

### Java 7 and older

With Java 7 and older, we need to use iteration and type checking:

```
public <T> void genericMethod(T t) {
    Set<String> strs = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<?> tAsSet;
    if (t instanceof Set<?>) {
        tAsSet = (Set<?>) t;
        for (Object obj : tAsSet) {
            if (obj instanceof String) {
                strs.add((String) obj);
            }
        }
        // Do something with strs here
    } else {
        // Throw an exception or log a warning or something.
    }
}
```

### Guava

As per Mark Peters' comment below, Guava also has methods that do this for you if you can add it to your project:

```
public <T> void genericMethod(T t) {
    if (t instanceof Set<?>) {
        Set<?> set = (Set<?>) t;
        if (Iterables.all(set, Predicates.instanceOf(String.class))) {
            Set<String> strs = (Set<String>) set;
            // Do something with strs here
        }
    }
}
```

The statement, `Iterables.all(set, Predicates.instanceOf(String.class))` is essentially the same thing as `set instanceof Set<String>`.

Comment: In Guava you can check if an `Iterable` contains only Strings using `Iterables.all(tAsSet, Predicates.instanceOf(String.class))`.  Or filter using `Iterables.filter(tAsSet, String.class)`.

Comment: @MarkPeters Guava always has neat little methods like that, good find.

Comment: It would be handy to have a method without instances... my case is a function `<T extends SomeInterface<K>> funcname(T obj)`, and I'd like to do some checking on the K type.

Comment: @Nyerguds To do that, just declare K first, like this: `<K extends Number, T extends SomeInterface<K>>`

Comment: @Brian That still doesn't help me get the class of K for type checking or creating instances...

Comment: @Nyerguds Then you'll need to pass in an instance of Class<K> either via a constructor or the method that requires it. There is no other way to type check or create instances of a generic type because of erasure.

Comment: @Brian Yeah... I hate that about Java. All of that stuff works fine in C# :(

Comment: Since Java 8 you don't need Guava to check if a `Set<?>` only contains Strings: `set.stream().allMatch((o) -> o instanceof String)`

Comment: @farsil: true! Even better: `set.stream().allMatch(String.class::isInstance)`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Checking the content of a collection seems to be a non-sense to me. What if the collection is empty?

Comment: @JeanValjean - the original question was geared around preventing runtime class cast exceptions when iterating over a collection. Since Java doesn't support `x instanceof List<String>` and similar, then in this sense, an empty collection will never throw a class cast exception. Think of it as similar to `null`. In Java, `null` is an instance of nothing (`x instanceof Y` is always `false` if `x` is `null`) but `null` can be cast to anything (I can still do `z = (Y) x` if `x` is `null`).

Answer (score 11):

You don't have that option in Java, sadly. In Java, there is no **runtime** difference between a `List<String>` and a `List<Integer>`. It is the **compiler** that ensures that you never `add()` an `Integer` to a `List<String>`. Even that compiler enforcement is not strict, so you can "legally" do such abominations with unchecked casts....

All in all, for (almost) any matter of runtime-type-identification, you have to take `List<String>` for what it actually is: just a raw `List`. That is called *type erasure*.

That said, nothing prevents you from inspecting the contents of a `List` for their types:

```
public boolean isListOf(List<?> list, Class<?> c) {
    for (Object o : list) {
        if (!c.isInstance(o)) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

To use this method:

```
    // ...
    if (genericObject instanceof List<?>) {
        if (isListOf((List<?>) genericObject, String.class)) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<String> strings = (List<String>) genericObject;
        }
    }
```

An interesting observation: if the `list` is empty, the method returns true for all given types. Actually there is no runtime difference between an empty `List<String>` and an empty `List<Integer>` *whatsoever*.