# java generics wildcards casting issue

Tags: java, generics

I have method as below

```
   void meth(List<?> list) {
       List<Integer> integers = (List<Integer>)list; //how do I make sure am casting correctly to List < Integer >? what if list passed as List< String > , then this will throw some RunTime Exceptions, how to avoid this?
    }
```

In above snippet, for meth(), am not sure which type of Arraylist will be passed, it could be List  or List etc, based on type of list type, I have to assign it to another list correctly, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You could try bounds-checking as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515861/how-to-check-if-a-generic-type-implements-a-specific-type-of-generic-interface-i

Comment: You cant, check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: This looks like a badly designed method. If `list` needs to be a `List<Integer>`, then declare the method parameter as `List<Integer>` instead of `List<?>`. Then you won't need to cast.

Comment: @Jesper My method has to accept List<Integer> , List<String> etc, in this case, shall I use meth(List<T>)   or   meth(List<?>) , may I know when to use wildcard parameters?

Comment: So, your method is really going to be different than what you presented in your question...? Because if you're going to cast it to `List<Integer>` then it makes no sense that your method should also accept `List<String>` etc.

Comment: You should use an unbounded wildcard (`?`) only if the method doesn't care / need to know what the actual type of the elements of the `List` is. Otherwise, use a bounded wildcard (`? extends Something`) or a type parameter (`T`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically ... you can't.   Since you *could* call `meth` (as you have written it) with a `List<String>` parameter, there can always be runtime exceptions.

Solutions:

- Declare `meth` as `public void meth(List<Integer> list)` so that you can't call it like this `meth(someStringList)`.  That avoids the unchecked type cast and eliminates the possibility of a class cast exception.
- Use `list` like this in `meth`.

  ```
  void meth(List<?> list) {
      for (Object o: list) {
          Integer i = (Integer) o;
          // ...
      }
  }
  ```

  We can still get the class cast exception, but at least we get rid of the compiler error about unchecked type casts.
- Use a `@SuppressWarning` annotation to suppress the compiler warning about the unchecked type cast.  Once again, you could get the exceptions.

---

Unfortunately, given Java's generic type parameter erasure, there is no way that the body of `meth` (as written) can find out what kind of list it has been called with at runtime.  And it won't work with a named type parameter either.

Answer (score 1):

I verified that it does not throw exception. With type erasure, all generics are convert to Object.  Generics are for compiler to enforce type during compile time.

```
   static List<Integer> meth(List<?> list){
      return (List<Integer>) list;
   }
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("world");
        strings.add("hello");
        List<Integer> integers = meth(strings);
        System.out.println(integers);
    }
```

Console:

```
[world, hello]
```

You can try the code here:  https://onlinegdb.com/z7DmGAJUI