# Check type of generic

Tags: java, android

I have this method:

```
public <T> void onMultipleSelectionTextFinished(
          @NonNull ArrayList<FMultipleSelectionText.HolderItem<T>> holderItems, 
          int payload) {
    // check here
}
```

How can I check inside of it that `holderItem` is of type `ArrayList<FMultipleSelectionText.HolderItem<EFunction>>` and if it is then cast it to that and handle if in a special way ?

**EDIT:**

I tried using `instanceof` but it says this:

[image]

Also, I went by the rout of castig it to `Object` first and then castig it again to what I needed, but it's not an elegant solution :(

Comment: If you require type specific functionality, don't use generics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that at the compile time because of [TypeErasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) at runtime. Alternatively you can do this using reflection, Guava API also provide methods to accomplish this task.
Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11799141/5803493).

Comment: Hmm ... I'm complicating my existence with that. I'll just need to change the entire structure if that's the only way. It would be quicker to do that than use reflection :)

Comment: You can give it a try. :) @AndreiBogdan