# Get Generic Type of an ArrayList declaration

Tags: java, generics, java-8

Lets say I have the following entity class with annotations etc.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FIRST_TABLE")
public class AnnotationTestClass implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -6159126853399658427L;

  @Column(name = "X1", length = 20)
  private String name;
  @Column(name = "EXTERN_KEY", precision = 15)
  private BigDecimal key;
```

Furthermore I have the following code part:

```
List<AnnotationTestClass> tableToBeExported = new ArrayList<>();

PTestX p = new PTestX(tableToBeExported);

p.method();
```

And the declaration of the above `PTestX` class.

```
  public class PTestX {
    private List<? extends Serializable> tableToBeExported;

    public PTestX(List<? extends Serializable> tableToBeExported) {
      this.tableToBeExported = tableToBeExported;
    }

    public void method() {
      ...
    }
  }
```

So what I like to to get is the type of the generic in the usage which means I want to have the result: `AnnotationTestClass` to access this entity and extract information from the `AnnotationTestClass` via reflection.

I have tried several approaches within the `method()` to get information like this:

```
public void method() {
  Type[] genericInterfaces = tableToBeExported.getClass().getGenericInterfaces();
  for (int i = 0; i < genericInterfaces.length; i++) {
    Type type = genericInterfaces[i];
    System.out.println("Type:" + type.getTypeName());
  }

  TypeVariable<?>[] typeParameters2 = tableToBeExported.getClass().getTypeParameters();
  for (int i = 0; i < typeParameters2.length; i++) {
    TypeVariable<?> typeVariable = typeParameters2[i];
    System.out.println("getTypeParameters: " + typeVariable.getGenericDeclaration());
  }

  Type[] classes = tableToBeExported.getClass().getGenericInterfaces();
  for (int i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    Type type = classes[i];
    System.out.println("i:" + i + " genericInterfaces: type:" + type.getTypeName());
    TypeVariable<?>[] typeParameters = type.getClass().getTypeParameters();
    for (int j = 0; j < typeParameters.length; j++) {
      TypeVariable<?> typeVariable = typeParameters[j];
      System.out.println("    tV:" + typeVariable.getName());
      Type[] genericSuperclass = typeVariable.getClass().getGenericInterfaces();
      for (int k = 0; k < genericSuperclass.length; k++) {
        Type type2 = genericSuperclass[k];
        System.out.println("    GS:" + type2.getTypeName());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

by using the above implementation of the `method` I will get the following output:

```
Type:java.util.List<E>
Type:java.util.RandomAccess
Type:java.lang.Cloneable
Type:java.io.Serializable
getTypeParameters: class java.util.ArrayList
i:0 genericInterfaces: type:java.util.List<E>
i:1 genericInterfaces: type:java.util.RandomAccess
    tV:T
    GS:java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable<D>
i:2 genericInterfaces: type:java.lang.Cloneable
    tV:T
    GS:java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable<D>
i:3 genericInterfaces: type:java.io.Serializable
    tV:T
    GS:java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable<D>
```

But at the moment I don't have found a way to get real type `AnnotationTestClass`.

The line with: `getTypeParameters: class java.util.ArrayList` looks promising but I don't have found a way to get further informations? Maybe I oversight something...maybe I'm on the wrong path...

I have found different answers:

- [Generic type of local variable at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798951/generic-type-of-local-variable-at-runtime) which say If I correctly understand that this is not possible based on type erasure? In particular with and empty list.

Others like this:
 * [Get generic type of java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list)

Comment: That’s impossible. An `ArrayList` instance doesn’t carry the generic signature you’ve used to create the instance. Yes, that’s Type Erasure.

Comment: @Holger would you post this as an answer so I give you the credit.

Comment: Basically the 2 questions that you link to indicate that this is not possible so what are you asking for exactly?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate... and things have not changes - you can't.