# Java Reflection - Getting value of nested object, list and array within object

Tags: java, reflection

I am new to reflection and trying to create a generalized function which will take in object and parse all the fields that are of type `String`, `String[]` or `List<String>`.  Any `String`, `String[]` or `List<String>` that is present in nested object has also to be parsed.  Is there any utility which can help me in doing that?  Getting the values from parent object (`User`) was simple - used `BeanUtils.describe(user);` - it gives the `String` values in parent object but not `String[]`, `List<String>` and nested object.  I am sure I might not be the first one who needs this feature? Are there any utilities or code which could help me achieve do this?

```
public class User {
    private String somevalue;
    private String[] thisArray;
    private List<String> thisList;
    private UserDefinedObject myObject;
    .
    .
    .

}
```

Comment: "I am sure I might not be the first one who needs this feature?" ... And I'm sure I'm not the first person to ask if you **really** need this feature.  'Cos so often people use reflection to do things that **should** be done non-reflectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`Class.getDeclaredFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29) will get you an array of `Field`s representing each field of the class. You could loop over these and check the type returned by [`Field.getType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType%28%29). Filtering fields of type `List` to `List<String>` is trickier - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list) for help with that.

After doing the first dynamic lookup of the fields you want, you should keep track of (memoize) the relevant `Field` objects for better performance.

Here's a quick example:

```
//for each field declared in User,
for (Field field : User.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    //get the static type of the field
    Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();
    //if it's String,
    if (fieldType == String.class) {
        // save/use field
    }
    //if it's String[],
    else if (fieldType == String[].class) {
        // save/use field
    }
    //if it's List or a subtype of List,
    else if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(fieldType)) {
        //get the type as generic
        ParameterizedType fieldGenericType =
                (ParameterizedType)field.getGenericType();
        //get it's first type parameter
        Class<?> fieldTypeParameterType =
                (Class<?>)fieldGenericType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        //if the type parameter is String,
        if (fieldTypeParameterType == String.class) {
            // save/use field
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I used reference equality (`==`) instead of `isAssignableFrom` to match `String.class` and `String[].class` since `String` is `final`.

**Edit:** Just noticed your bit about finding nested `UserDefinedObject`s. You could apply recursion to the above strategy in order to search for those.