# Trying to find class within List

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get generic type of java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list)

How can I see what type is within a list in a parameter

```
private List<String> names;
```

how would I be able to find out that its a list of Strings? My goal is to make a method like this working:

```
public Field findFieldByObjectType(Class<?> clazz, Object obj) {
    for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        // if field type is List<obj>
        // return field
    }
}
```

Comment: This OS question should give you some clues: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3403909/1916110

Comment: Do you want the static type (as declared) or the type of the elements in a specific instance?

Comment: This is the closest thing you can achieve http://stackoverflow.com/a/1942680/1317692

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, this is the closest thing what you can achieve with the help of reflection https://stackoverflow.com/a/1942680/1317692.
Credit goes to BalusC.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `instanceof` operator or the `getClass()` method on the element(s) of the list.

```
private List<String> names;
```

becomes

```
private List names;
```

after type erasure.

Comment: But how can I do getClass() on the elements? The list isnt even initialized

Comment: The getClass() works at runtime by when you should have it initilized.

Comment: @MooseMoose you cannot, since `.getClass()` is a runtime operation, and the generic type is erased at runtime (this is called type erasure). IOW, there is no such thing as `List<Something>.class`, at runtime, it becomes `List.class`.

Comment: No since I'm only getting the fields from the Class<?>, it will never be initialized

Comment: thats not true, when I'm printing field.getGenericType() it gives me java.util.List<java.lang.String>