# How to identify the returned object's type of a method?

Tags: java, generics

I have a helper class which gets notified by the below method

```
public void setObject(Object obj) {
    this.obj =  obj
}
```

There is getter method for the obj. Is there any way to identify the caller about the type of the obj. The object can take any object like :

```
List<Switch>
Switch
List<Link>
```

The caller has to process the obj after calling the getter method. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can always know the class (and then the class name) from `obj.getClass()`. What you want to do with it further ?

If you want to invoke methods on the obj - You need reflection..
Something like this -

```
Class myClass = obj.getClass();
Method m = myClass.getDeclaredMethod("get",new Class[] {});
Object result = m.invoke(myObject,null);
```

Comment: `obj.getClass()` gives you a `Class` object. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html to get its name use `obj.getClass().getName()`

Comment: yeah.. added what to do after getting the class.

Comment: After getting the object, we need to invoke some methods. Using reflection will be cumbersome because the object is an instance of many objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could know the object type using `instanceof` operator.Consider the following example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (getObject() instanceof A) {
            System.out.println("A class");
        }
        if (getObject() instanceof B) {
            System.out.println("B class");
        }
        if (getObject() instanceof List) {
            System.out.println("List class");
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return Object type. 
     */
    public static Object getObject() {
        //Change this value to new A() or new B();
        return new ArrayList<A>();
    }
}
class A {

    private String aName;

    public A(String aName) {
        this.aName = aName;
    }

    public String getaName() {
        return aName;
    }

    public void setaName(String aName) {
        this.aName = aName;
    }
}

class B {

    private String bName;

    public B(String bName) {
        this.bName = bName;
    }

    public String getbName() {
        return bName;
    }

    public void setbName(String bName) {
        this.bName = bName;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a method returning object type and if you are gonna change the returning value of that method you can easily understand what is going on.And one more thing you can't guess the generic types at runtime because "Generic types are erased before runtime".Hope you got my point.Cheers

Comment: The object can be an instance of many objects. There will be many if else conditions. Any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. It informs you how to get the parameterized type.

[Get generic type of java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list)