# Instantiate and store generic arrays

Tags: java, arrays, generics, reflection

Good day everyone. My problem has been discussed many times on SO, but i cant find answer anyway.
So, I need to store array of generics in my generic class instance:

```
public class GenericArrayStorage<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {

    private Item[] storage;
    ....
}
```

Obviously, I cant work with `storage` like with array of concrete objects (my IDE shows error `Generic array creation` on `new Item[]`). After some research i wrote this code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public GenericArrayStorage() {
    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = 
       (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass(); //error
    Class clazz = (Class) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    storage = (Item[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, 10);
}
```

But this leads to following error:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType`

I said OK and wrote this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public GenericArrayStorage() {
    ParameterizedType pt = 
       (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0]; 
    Class clazz = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0]; //error
    storage = (Item[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, 10);
}
```

This one causes another exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class`. Sad but true.

Then I added `.getClass()` to `pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0]` and my constructor now don't throw any errors. However, when i try to work with this array after `new GenericArrayStorage<Integer>()`, it throws following: `java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Integer`. This line causes exception: `storage[0] = new Integer(1);`

So, how could i work with generic array?

Comment: In your first attempt, you get a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType` because your class implements an interface. The superclass would be `java.lang.Object` and that is not a `ParametrizedType`.

Comment: @Tunaki It's clear now why i got those exceptions. But this doesn't answer the question: how could one implement a generic array storage without strange reflection issues?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14659922/1743880).

Comment: What's the problem with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java

Comment: Side note: you won't have this problem if you use a `List` instead, code is much cleaner and understandable (`storage = new ArrayList<>()`)

Answer (score 0):

The only way this works is if the value of `Item` is captured in a type definition. Ex:

```
StringStorage extends GenericArrayStorage<String> {
}
```

Then your `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` should work as expected, returning `String` in this case.