# How to check Type in android

Tags: java, android, gson

One of my function getting **[Type](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Type.html)** variable. sometimes it can be `java.util.List<Test$MyClass>` or `java.util.List<java.lang.String>` so how can I identify them?

```
if (type instanceof List) {

}
```

Both are List type but different type. So that above code does not work.
I want to distinguish between the two list types.

my main issue is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596112/implement-jsondeserializer-more-than-one-in-gson-in-android

I am using `deserializer` for that..

```
public class Data implements JsonDeserializer<ArrayList<MyClass1>> {
public ArrayList<MyClass1> myList1 = new ArrayList<MyClass1>();
public ArrayList<MyClass2> myList2 = new ArrayList<MyClass2>();

@Override
public ArrayList<MyClass1> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    Debug.e("", type.toString());

    ArrayList<Layoutmap> data = new ArrayList<Layoutmap>();

    try {
        if (json.isJsonObject()) {

            // my stuff

            return data;
        } else {
            return new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return data;
}
```

}

above code works for `public ArrayList<MyClass2> myList2 = new ArrayList<MyClass2>();` and `myList2` is also i want to deserialize..
It's part of google [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: Do you want to distinguish between the two list types?

Comment: IMHO, this indicates a design problem. You shouldn't have a method returning sometimes something, and some other times something else.

Comment: Agree with JB Nizet. But if you want to compare each element for some reason then you could check my ans.

Comment: Type is not list type.. see my updated question....

Comment: [the first answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list) may be usefull in your case. tl;dr: use reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find my solution .. I don't know it is better or not

I am comparing two `Type` variable like this...

```
if (type.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                new TypeToken<List<Test.MyClass>>() {
                }.getType().toString())) {

}else
{

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, the problem is that in Java an instance test against a type that is not reifiable is always an error.

For example:

```
if(o instance of List<E>)
```

where E is any type, will not compile.

You simply have to check that what's contained in the Lists are the same type, e.g.

```
if(list1.get(0) instance of String && list2.get(0) instance of String)
```

**EDIT:**

Not sure if there's a language barrier issue here (your question is hard to fully understand), but you should not need to make your method take an argument of type Type. As someone else mentioned, you have a bad design here. What you should be doing is simply defining how to deserialize each of your classes (if custom deserialization needs to be defined *at all*; that is, if the defaults won't work) and then get a list of those in the regular way with Gson.

I'm not super familiar with Gson, but it should be something like:

```
List<Class1> stuff = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Class1>>(){}.getType());
```

So, in other words, if each class has peculiarities that will make default deserialization not work, then there's no way (without a lot of gymnastics) to make a `deserialize` method work for every single type.

Also, don't combine all functionality into one. Getting an `ArrayList<LayoutMap>` should be separated from the functionality of deserializing each class.

Comment: please see updated question... and i don't have list before excution

Answer (score 2):

try to use getClass() function on your type to find the class of an object on runtime.
for eg..
 type.getClass().equals(java.lang.string)

Answer (score 1):

You can just try something like :

```
for (int i=0; i<type.size(); ++i) {
    if (type.get(i) instanceof String) {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

This would check each element of the list and if its a string you could work on it.

Comment: It is not possible to identify type when the list is empty with your solution

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, `type` will be an instance of `ParameterizedType`. So you can use the method [getActualTypeArguments()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments()).