# How to determine the class of grails domain array field

Tags: grails, groovy

For example, we have the next classes

```
class AAA {
    String fieldA
}

class BBB {
    AAA aaa
}
```

And now, after I run the:

```
GrailsClassUtils.getPropertyType(BBB.class, "aaa")
```

I've got an "AAA" as the result. But if code will look as:

```
class BBB {
    static hasMany = [aaa: AAA]
}
```

I've got an "java.util.Set" as the result. It is correct, but what I must to do if I need the result as
 "java.util.Set<AAA>" or better as "AAA"?

Actually I must ask "BBB" is the "aaa.fieldA" legal construction if "aaa" is "Set" or another "Collection" (List, Map, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
Class type = BBB.hasMany.aaa
```

As `hasMany` is just a static Map.  To get back the generic type of a Collection you could [try something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list).