# Get types of list objects at runtime

Tags: java, generics

Currently I have two lists

```
private List<Department> subdepts = new LinkedList<Department>();
private List<Employee> employees = new LinkedList<Employee>();
```

At runtime I get those as objects, but I need to know when I see a `List<Department>`

I got away with the following code.

```
// o is an Object
if(o instanceof List){
    List l = (List)o;
    if(l.size() > 0){
    if(l.get(0) instanceof Department){
```

But what do I do if the list is empty? How do I know if it is a `List<Department>`?

Comment: `if(!l.isEmpty()) { ... }`?

Comment: But the real question is, where is `o` coming from and why don't you know whether it's a `List` or not?

Comment: I guess there is no way to determine whether the *empty list* is of `Department` or that of `Employee`

Comment: Because I need to use reflection, and every members/methods get saved as an object. Then I have to iterate over those objects.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list

Comment: @RobeEleckers Yes that would be my workaround but it is a little bit ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic parameter types are erased at runtime, meaning you cannot determine the list's declared generic type. This is called [generic type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

If you know the list only will contain objects of one type, you could simply check if any object in the list is an instance of your specific class, but this is an unclear work-around.

Comment: yes that's what I thought. If the list is empty there is no way to know if it could hold departments or employees. :(