# How to give the And condition in Generics in java

Tags: java

We have a class structure like `A<-B<-C<-D<-E<-F` ( B extends A, C extends B and so on ).

I need to create a method `acceptList(List<> list)` in such a way that it can accept the `List` of Class `A,C,E` and do not accept List of `B,D,F`.

*This question was asked to me in an interview.*

Comment: Every `E` is a `B` and a `D`, among other parents `A`,`C`.

Comment: That’s impossible. And it doesn’t seam to make much sense either.

Comment: Your inheritance hierarchy is horrific.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that a method can *accept* some parameters? Should (in case of wrong argument types) the invocation be rejected by the type checker at compile time? Or should it throw InvalidArgumentExceptions? Or maybe something else?

Comment: Are you required to differentiate on the type of the list (e.g. `A` in `List<A>`) or on the type of the *elements* in the list (e.g. a `B` inside a `List<>`)?

Comment: I think by accept means "return true" rather that accept parameters. Could you be more precise.

Comment: There's just too much ambiguity. Assuming that the runtime type of the elements should be checked, what should be done with an empty list? Or a list of mixed elements (`A`s and `B`s)?

Comment: I believe this was a case in which you should have asked "What do you mean by ``accept``?". I bet they expected you to ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

Some trick like this might work, bear in mind that interfaces will always beat reflection ... thus if you can implement those type dependent functions in your interfaces directly then do it.

First your implementation of the classes:

```
public class A {

public boolean isAcceptable() {
    return true;
}

static class B extends A {

    @Override
    public boolean isAcceptable() {
        return !super.isAcceptable();
    }
}

static class C extends B {
    @Override
    public boolean isAcceptable() {
        return !super.isAcceptable();
    }
}

static class D extends C {
    @Override
    public boolean isAcceptable() {
        return !super.isAcceptable();
    }
}

static class E extends D {
    @Override
    public boolean isAcceptable() {
        return !super.isAcceptable();
    }
}

static class F extends E {
    @Override
    public boolean isAcceptable() {
        return !super.isAcceptable();
    }
}
```

}

then your acceptList(~):

```
public static boolean acceptList(List<? extends A> list){
    for (A a : list) {
        if(!a.isAcceptable()){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is not a type safe solution. Incompatibility will be revealed only at runtime. This may answer the question but is a practice that should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Absolutely right, but I believe the nature of is question is "at runtime", from the name of the function. Or else it is a bad case of the "bad-name-itis".

Comment: @allprog could you explaing your "disclaimer"?

Comment: Don't know whether it really answers the question, but I find the idea is just great! :)

Comment: @le_douard forget it, this is a great solution. It would be better if the value of acceptable did not rely so heavily on the actual hierarchy as it make the function really brittle. Suppose the next question was to implement the same functionality but all interfaces simply extended A.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the usage of condition - `if` and `isInstance()` ?

Comment: `instanceof` does not work for generic types, you can't test for `instanceof List<A>`. One solution would be to test the run-time class of the list's elements (e.g. `list.get(0)`), but even then you could have `B` elements inside a `List<A>`.

Comment: I think the interview question is probing to see if the interviewee will say "type erasure", and point out that generic restrictions will only be checked at compile time

Comment: No, it won't help a thing. You can't say *anything* about the element type of an empty list at run-time, and even if there are elements in the list you can't conclude anything about the element type of the list. You won't notice *any* difference between a `List<A>` full of `B`s and a `List<B>` full of `B`s at run-time. I agree with @GrahamGriffiths, this looks like a trick question.

Comment: Looking at the question again, it doesn't clarify if the method should accept based on the *generic type* or on the *type of the elements in the list*. The first cannot be done, the second can be done by checking the `getClass()` of each element. I added a comment to the OP.

Comment: You are rigth. The List of A can contain B elements. We can only check the objects inside the list.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, you can only specify allowed classes not classes that are not allowed.

Futhermore once a method is defined to accept a `List<? extends A>` it accepts `List<A>`, `List<B>`, `List<C>`,...

Answer (score 0):

Generics do not allow differentiation. The type erasure will play its tricks.. I would suggest you to write a custom logic like the below:

```
public class Test {

public boolean accept(List<? extends A> list) {
    for (Object o : list) {
        if (o instanceof E && !(o instanceof F))
            return true;
        else if (o instanceof C && !(o instanceof D) && !(o instanceof F))
            return true;
        else if (o instanceof A && !(o instanceof B) && !(o instanceof D) && !(o instanceof F))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    return false;

}

}

class A {

}

class B extends A {

}

class C extends B {

}

class D extends C {

}

class E extends D {

}

class F extends E {

}
```

Test Method to test the above code:

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    Test t = new Test();

    List<F> listF = new ArrayList<F>();
    listF.add(new F());
    System.out.println("List of F returns "+ t.accept(listF));

    List<E> listE = new ArrayList<E>();
    listE.add(new E());
    System.out.println("List of E returns "+ t.accept(listE));

    List<D> listD = new ArrayList<D>();
    listD.add(new D());
    System.out.println("List of D returns "+ t.accept(listD));

    List<C> listC = new ArrayList<C>();
    listC.add(new C());
    System.out.println("List of C returns "+ t.accept(listC));

    List<B> listB = new ArrayList<B>();
    listB.add(new B());
    System.out.println("List of B returns "+ t.accept(listB));

    List<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>();
    listA.add(new A());
    System.out.println("List of A returns "+ t.accept(listA));
}
```

Output of the test:

```
List of F returns false
List of E returns true
List of D returns false
List of C returns true
List of B returns false
List of A returns true
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to do some more research, this might help you . [Get generic type of java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list)

Comment: 1) D is instance of C, B is instance fo A, it will always return true.
2) List<A> can contain B elements.

Comment: yeah my bad...this has to be modified.

Comment: It partially works. It works for the objects inside the list, not the list itself. For example: `List<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>();
    listA.add(new B());`, because B is A

Comment: You can achieve this only if you have the list as a field in the class. For method parameters even reflection wont help.