# how the type information is retrieved in generics (Erasure) in Java?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

by using generics, we detect any possible during compilation.
for example,

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
//list.add(new Integer(45)); This will cause compilation error.
list.add("car");
list.add("bus");
list.add("bike");
String vehicle = list.get(0); //compiler-generated cast
```

when we use raw type instead of generics before Java 1.5,  it needs explicit casting.
for example,

```
List list2 = new ArrayList();
    list.add("car");
    list.add("bus");
    list.add("bike");
    String vehicle = (String)list.get(0); //explicit casting is necessary
```

however with generics, type erasure occurs. that is the type information is lost in runtime.
if, that is so, how does the JVM know what object type it is retrieving during runtime, whether it is a string object or a person object (compiler generated cast above). but this valid with generics, which is can cause runtime errors.

```
List<Object> test = new ArrayList<Object>();
            test.add("hello");
            test.add(new Integer(34));
```

finally, Joshua Bloch mentions on page 115 (item 23, effective java) that 
`Set<Object>` is parameterized type representing a set that can contain objects of any type,
`Set<?>` is a wild card type representing a set that can contain only objects of some unknown type
and `Set` is a raw type, which opts out of the generic type system.

I do understand what he means by the above statement. some clarifications will help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler inserts cast operations when retrieving items from generic methods; this is the only way that the JVM knows to treat the result of `list.get(0)` as a `String`. This is why heap pollution (inserting the wrong type of object into a generic collection) can result in a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Regarding the wildcards:

- `Set<Object>`'s generic type is exactly `Object`. You can insert and retrieve `Object` instances from it, but you can't pass a `Set<Integer>` to a method expecting a `Set<Object>`, since the method might be planning to add a non-`Integer` object to the set.
- `Set<?>` has an unspecified generic type. A method can retrieve anything from it as an `Object` (since everything is an `Object`) and can call universal methods on it like `hashCode` or `toString`, but it can't add anything to the set.
- `Set`, as you mention, is the raw type and shouldn't be used in new code.

Comment: can you provide with an example to illustrate the first two points regarding wildcards, Thanks

Comment: A method for pretty-printing a collection might take a `Collection<?>`, since it doesn't need to know the type of the collection's contents to call `toString` on them. If you declared it as `Collection<Object>`, you couldn't pass a `Collection<Integer>` to it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure, but what I understand by **type information is lost at runtime** is that **there is no way at runtime that a collection is of some specific type**. If you add a `String` to a collection, it will be a `String` only but the collection does not enforce that all elements should be of type `String`

Answer (score 0):

> Generics are implemented by Java compiler as a front-end conversion
>   called erasure. Type erasure applies to the use of generics. When
>   generics are used, they're converted into **compile time checks and run
>   time type casts**.

Due to type erasure mechanism this code:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("foo");
String x = a.get(0);
```

gets compiled into this:

```
List a = new ArrayList();
a.add("foo");
String x = (String) a.get(0);
```

Notice extra cast inserted into compiled compiled-code after type erasure.

*PS: @chrylis has already provided good explanation about your 2nd part of question.*

Answer (score 0):

Well, this stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list) can help you .

Eclipse might be using this method to find out the fields in a class and their generic type if any. Please have a look.