# How to get Generic Return type of a method using Reflections

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way get the return type of a generic method- return type?

```
public interface MyGeneric<T> {
  T doSomething();
}

public interface MyElement extends MyGeneric<Element> {

}

public class Main {
  public static final void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(MyElement.class.getMethod("doSomething", new Class<?>[0]).magic()); // => Element
  }
}
```

Using Method.getReturnType() I get java.lang.Object without. Does the method "magic" exist?

Comment: It is possible to check this at runtime :
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime>

Comment: I assume `interface MyElement<Element> ` should actually be `interface MyElement extends MyGeneric<Element>`?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. It seems likely as "doSomething" when looked up will result in a NoSuchMethodException when invoked on MyElement.

Comment: Sorry, fixed that typo

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, the reflection capabilities in the core Java library are rather poor for analyzing generic types.  You can use the `getGeneric...` methods (e.g., `getGenericReturnType()`), but they don't work all that well, and they usually return `Type` instances instead of `Class` instances.  I find this very clumsy to work with.

I have written my own reflection API, based the .NET's, which I feel is more consistent (particularly where generics are concerned).  Consider the following output:

```
import com.strobel.reflection.Type;

interface MyGeneric<T> {
    T doSomething();
}

interface Element {}

interface MyElement extends MyGeneric<Element> {}

class Main {
    public static final void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        // prints "class java.lang.Object":
        System.out.println(
            MyElement.class.getMethod("doSomething").getReturnType()
        );
        // prints "T":
        System.out.println(
            MyElement.class.getMethod("doSomething").getGenericReturnType()
        );
        // prints "Element":
        System.out.println(
            Type.of(MyElement.class).getMethod("doSomething").getReturnType()
        );
    }
}
```

You're welcome to use [my library](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/overview).  I actually just committed a bug fix that prevented this example from working (it's in the tip of the `develop` branch).

Comment: Type.of(MyElement.class).getMethod("doSomething").getReturnType() looks like what I'm searching for. Would you tell me how you implemented it (general strategy or Link to the Class your Sourcecode)?

Comment: The relevant code is spread out over a couple classes.  The code which translates `java.lang.reflect` types and members into the form used by my APIs is in `com.strobel.reflection.Resolver`.  The abstract class for all types is `com.strobel.reflection.Type`, and from there you can find the classes it calls to populate and cache the full list of declared and inherited members.  The repository root for the reflection framework is [here](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/src/b2a544ae017a7919bfceab11e3e1556b78442503/Procyon.Reflection?at=develop).

Comment: If I have some method with a return type or parameter that is a parameterized type -- e.g., public void setMyIntMaybe(Option[Int] intMaybe) -- then the inner type will be erased and it will show in this case as Option[Object] -- same for return type or parameter type of method. Strobel's library is nice but doesn't overcome this limitation.

Comment: @SamerAdra That should not be the case.  Are you using a JVM language other than Java?  I have not tested my generics reflection support with Scala, Kotlin, or any other language.

Comment: @MikeStrobel, I was using Scala. Fortunately I was able to throw something together that should work for Scala 2.10.4+: https://github.com/FINRAOS/DataGenerator/blob/master/dg-common/src/main/code/org/finra/datagenerator/common/Helpers/ReflectionHelper.scala (in method "invokeScalaSetter").

Answer (score 1):

No, that magic does not exist generally. If you want to make a trick in order to get to that data, you can require that data in your interface like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime).

On the other side, if your type is special (like a List), you can do that. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list) for special types.

Comment: There are no "special types". If you're referring to answers [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1942680/2891664), those work because they're e.g. retrieving the type in the field declaration.