# How to get a returned List of Objects object type from a Java method?

Tags: java, list, object, generics, methods

I have a getter method in a Class that returns a list of objects. It looks something like this:

```
public List <cars> getCars() {

// some code here

}
```

The class contains some other getters as well as this one. In another Class, I want to get all the getter methods contained in the first class and display the name of the methods and the returned data types.

I'm able to get the name of the above method (getCars) and it's returned data type (List). However, I can't seem to get "Cars" as the type of object that the list contains. The best I can get is "ObjectType". Is there a way of getting "Cars" to be displayed? I've read about Type Erasure and how Generics are removed in the bytecode as it's only used for the benefit of the Java compiler. Is my problem related to Type Erasure?

Is it possible to get the word "Cars" displayed? When I read about Type Erasure there seems to be a way to get Generics from a List but the examples I've seen are for String and Integer and not objects.

[Get generic type of java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list)

Thanks

Comment: How are you "getting" the name of the method at present?  I assume you're using reflection at runtime, but this isn't necessarily clear.  An example of your current code that returns `"ObjectType"` would be helpful.

Comment: In your question you state: the examples I've seen are for String and Integer and not objects", String and Integer are Objects, not basic types.

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle, yes I'm using Reflection. I followed the article written by Jenkov on http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html under the section "Generic Method Return Types". It uses ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) returnType;
Type[] typeArguments = type.getActualTypeArguments();

Comment: @Joeblade, true. I'm new to Java. Didn't mean to confuse you with my terminology. I was meaning a user defined object eg car

Comment: @user3572079 no problem just thought I'd point out that user defined classes and system defined classes are both objects, in case you thought there were special rules there, which there are not. the only exception is the + operator which is hardwired to String (or toString() instance method) in string context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get hold of the (generic) information about a method using standard Java reflection:

```
Class<?> yourClass = Class.forName("a.b.c.ClassThatHasTheMethod");
Method getCarsMethod = yourClass.getMethod("getCars");
Type returnType = getCarsMethod.getGenericReturnType();
```

Now there's not a particularly elegant way to handle this `returnType` variable (that I know of).  It could be a plain `Class`, or it could be any of the [subinterfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) (e.g. `ParameterizedType`, which it is in this case).  In the past when I've done this, I've just had to use `instanceof` and casting to handle the cases.  For example:

```
if (returnType instanceof Class<?>) {
    Class<?> returnClass = (Class<?>)returnType;
    // do something with the class
}
else if (returnType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
    // This will be the case in your example
    ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType)returnType;
    Type rawType = pt.getRawType();
    Type[] genericArgs = pt.getActualTypeArguments();

    // Here `rawType` is the class "java.util.List",
    // and `genericArgs` is a one element array containing the
    // class "cars".  So overall, pt is equivalent to List<cars>
    // as you'd expect.
    // But in order to work that out, you need
    // to call something like this method recursively, to
    // convert from `Type` to `Class`...
}
else if (...) // handle WildcardType, GenericArrayType, TypeVariable for completeness
```

Comment: After reading this I've removed my answer, as it can be misleading. Another thing I learnt in SO!

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle. Thx Andrzej, I've now got it do what I want. I'm not sure what happened but following your example gave me the answer I needed. I'm not sure where I went wrong beforehand but I'm sure there must have been some user error involved (as I was trying lots of ideas) but your explanations clarified things for me. Thx for picking up my question.