# Generics - Get the reference type

Tags: java, generics, reflection, arraylist

I have a problem to get the type of a list. The problem is While declaring I'm not specifying the type. I'm setting it only at run time.

I have a POJO class

```
public class MyObject<T> {

    private String name;
    private List<T> list;

//getter and setter
}
```

I have followed [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list) and tried my below code

```
public class ListType {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        ListType listType = new ListType();
    List<Integer> listInt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    MyObject<Integer> myObjectInt = new MyObject<Integer>();
    myObjectInt.setList(listInt);
    listType.initialize(myObjectInt);

    MyObject<String> myObjectStr = new MyObject<String>();
    List<String> listStr = new ArrayList<String>();
    myObjectStr.setList(listStr);
    listType.initialize(myObjectStr);
    }

    private void initialize(MyObject myObject) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        List list = myObject.getList();
        ListType listType = new ListType();
        listType.getListType(list);
    }

    private void getListType(List list) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        Field stringListField = MyObject.class.getDeclaredField("list");
        ParameterizedType stringListType = (ParameterizedType) stringListField.getGenericType();
        Class<?> stringListClass = (Class<?>) stringListType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        System.out.println(stringListClass);
    }

}
```

Then I am getting following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
    at com.sample.listtype.ListType.getListType(ListType.java:35)
    at com.sample.listtype.ListType.initialize(ListType.java:27)
    at com.sample.listtype.ListType.main(ListType.java:15)
```

How to get the type if I'm setting at run time?

Comment: *But how to get the type if I'm setting at run time?* A List has no type at run time ([erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)) so the question doesn't really make sense. Better to tell us about what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that what you want to achieve is possible. However, a little change to the code can do the trick:

```
public class MyObject {
    private List<?> list;
    private Class<?> type;

    public <T> void setList(List<T> list, Class<T> c) {
        this.list = list;
        this.type = c;
    }

    public List<?> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public Class<?> getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException,
        SecurityException {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
    myObject.setList(list, Integer.class);

    System.out.println(myObject.getType());
}
```

Output:

```
class java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: Maybe making the whole `MyObject` class generic would be an option for OP too. It would not avoid the extra parameter because of type erasure, but would introduce a little more type safety.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code. Please check. Now is there anyway how can I get the type?

Comment: @AndreStannek indeed making MyObject a generic class would be a lot safer, but then it would be possible to set the list to any type. I.e. MyObject<Integer> can not set any lists of Double, and I guess that this functionality is necessary from the question.

Comment: @iProgrammer, you get the type by calling the getType() method of MyObject as shown in the example.

Comment: `MyObject<Integer> myObjectInt = new MyObject<Integer>();` I'm doing this. So why I need to declare a separate vairable and set and get through methods?

Comment: @iProgrammer it's because of type erasure. There is no generic type information at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The method [`getGenericType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType%28%29) has the return type [`Type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) which, amongst others, can be `Class` or `ParameterizedType`. It makes sense to me that it wouldn't return `ParameterizedType` if invoked on a field which has no parameterized type. It seems to return `Class` in this case. The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType%28%29) is a little inconclusive on this one.

As for your question on how to get the actual type at runtime: Generic type information is erased at runtime. It is only used to ensure type safety at compile time. When you assign an object with the actual type `ArrayList<Integer>` to a variable with the static type `List`, you can't get the generic type of the actual object at runtime. What you could do is check the type of the objects contained in the list:

```
Class<?> foo = list.get(0).getClass();
```

Comment: this is a nice workaround, but it won't work when the list doesn't have any elements in it...

Comment: Yeah, What if the list is empty?

Comment: @NielsBillen Yeah, in that case it won't work ;-) I like your answer, I had to do something similar once.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code. Please check. Now is there anyway how can I get the type?