# How to find a class of type variable in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

How can I find the class of `XOperation` via Reflection API in Java?

```
public interface Operation<P extends Parameters> {
}

public class XParameters implements Parameters<XOperation> {
}
```

I'm trying to implement this method.

```
public <O extends Operation<P>, P extends Parameters> O getOperationByParametersClass(Class<P> parametersClass) {
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: So you want to pass e.g. `XParameters.class` to `getOperationByParametersClass` and it should return `XOperation.class`? Or...?

Comment: Yeap, that is what I want.

Comment: You probably want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list and http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html (but comes with limitations)

Comment: In your example, there is no way to get the type of P by reflection.  The information is simply not available at runtime ... due to type erasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce a member in `Parameters` that will hold the `Class` of the type-parameter.

For example:

```
abstract class Parameters<T> {
    protected Class<T> type;
}
```

Then, in the `getOperationByParametersClass()` method, you should pass an instance of `Parameters` (including subclasses):

```
public <O extends Operation, P extends Parameters<O>> Class<O> 
             getOperationByParametersClass(P parametersInstance) {
    return parametersInstance.type;
}
```

Comment: I agree with this, just passing the `Class` is still the most reliable solution.