# How to get type of array elements, in Clojure, from fields declared in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, clojure

The following code

```lisp
(-> (.getField (Class/forName
                "ccg.flow.processnodes.text.retrievers.Dictionary.Dictionary")
     "wordsTuples") .getType)
```

tells me that `wordsTuples` is a `java.util.ArrayList`.  But what I would like to be able to learn is that it is an *ArrayList with elements of type `String[]`*, since it happens to be declared like this:

```java
public class Dictionary extends ProcessNode {
    public ArrayList<String[]> wordsTuples;

    public ArrayList<String> words;
...
```

Is there a way to obtain the "type hint" information programmatically within Clojure?

Comment: I think this IntelliJ Plugin does what you're looking for: https://cursiveclojure.com/

Comment: "It will be a commercial product, with pricing to be released soon." - I'd like a generic solution.

Comment: I think you can use `class` instead of that more complicated expression to identify the object as an `ArrayList`.  e.g. `(class (java.util.ArrayList. ["a" "b" "c"])) ;=> java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: This question appears to be incorrectly titled. Type-hints in Clojure are there to improve performance of certain operations by hinting types to the Clojure compiler. The question's real concern appears to be about how one would obtain the generic type parameter from a generic Java collection. Perhaps asker would like to revise the title?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list

Comment: This is a duplicate of: stackoverflow.com/questions/14402585/how-do-you-get-listtype-with-reflection - I voted to close and it was removed wtf. If you want free stackoverflow points, port that answer to Java interop now, lol.

Comment: @ScottLowe thanks, I've revised the title to be more descriptive, and I put _type hints_ in scare quotes in the body of the question.

Comment: @Bill, thanks that link seems to have what I needed.  I modified the example code into a candidate answer, below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1942692/821010) on the question [Get generic type of java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list).  And from there, a simple modification of my sample code now works as desired:

```clj
(-> (.getField (Class/forName
             "ccg.flow.processnodes.text.retrievers.Dictionary.Dictionary")
     "wordsTuples") .getGenericType)
```

Returns:

```
#<ParameterizedTypeImpl java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String[]>>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, because of type erasure.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

There is a wealth of data on your erasure on google.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a simple hack based on fact which data is in your list.

E.g. you have got some list of strings:

```
(def lst (java.util.ArrayList. ["my" "list" "of" "strings"]))
```

Then you can get type of item:

```
(if (and (instance? java.util.List lst) 
         (not (.isEmpty lst))) 
   (.getName (.getClass (.get lst 0))))
```

Drawback of this workaround is that you cannot get reflection info about empty list b/c of erasure mentioned by [freakhill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1544731/freakhill), but who cares about empty lists ;)?

Hope this helps.