# getting type of element in a List in which List is the return type of method in java

Tags: java, reflection, collections

I got every methods in my package using reflections and then based on the return type of every method, I want to do some operations. 
But unfortunately I had a problem with collections. when I find a method in which return a collection like a List, I can't find a way to get to know about the type of List's element.
I used the code below to get the return type of my methods.

```
if (method.getReturnType().equals(List.class)){
    statement;
}
```

The above code does work well and gets every method which return a List but it is just return java.util.List as a return type and I can't find a way to get to know about the type of element in that List.
For instance, if I have a method like this:

```
public List<CmsCustomerModel> getCustomerModel(){
    statement;
}
```

I don't know how can I get CmsCustomerModel class as a type of element for return List. I would be wonder if anyone help me find this. Please guide me.

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list

Comment: Thank you in advance for your comment @wawek . I saw that question before, on that example they declared those Lists as fields in the class, so they can use `getGenericType()` method which work for **Fields**. But I used `getReturnType()` which return a **class**. So, as it returns java.util.List class. I can't use that solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getGenericReturnType` which returns a `Type` rather than a `Class`, and allows you to get at all the type arguments etc. Short but complete example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        for (Method method : Test.class.getMethods()) {
            System.out.println(method.getName());
            Type type = method.getGenericReturnType();
            System.out.println("Return type: " + type.getTypeName());
            if (type instanceof ParameterizedType)
            {
                ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) type;
                System.out.println("Parameterized: " + pt.getRawType());
                for (Type arg : pt.getActualTypeArguments())
                {
                    System.out.println("  " + arg);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Integer> getNumbers() {
        return null;
    }

    public static List<String> getStrings() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Output includes:

```
getStrings
Return type: java.util.List<java.lang.String>
Parameterized: interface java.util.List
  class java.lang.String
getNumbers
Return type: java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>
Parameterized: interface java.util.List
  class java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: This is really good feature. And I always thought Jon Skeet has expertize in C# only.

Comment: @Panther: Do you mean C#? I hardly know C++ at all :)

Comment: Thanks for you're response @JonSkeet . It works well just like what I want.