# Get class type of "?" in ArrayList<? extends Class>

Tags: java, arraylist

I know there's tons of similar questions around but I really didn't find a valid answer to my question.

I have an abstract class `Entity`.
Then I have these two classes, `Biker` and `Pedestrian`, both extending `Entity`.

I need to perform operations on two `ArrayList` of both classes,
to do so, I have a method

```
private void handleEntities(ArrayList<? extends Entity> entities) {...};
```

This method should update both the `ArrayList`.

Given that both the `ArrayList<Biker>` and `ArrayList<Pedestrian>` may be empty, is there a way to get which of the two classes the method is working with? I know I could pass some other parameter to the method, I just want to know if I could do something like `entities.getObjectClass()` which would eventually return `Biker` or `Pedestrian`.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**
As requested, the use-case:

```
private void handleEntities(ArrayList<? extends Entity> entities) {
    // an hypothetical switch case
    if (entities.getObjectClass().toString() == Biker.class.getSimpleName())
        // add element to Biker ArrayList
    else if (entities.getObjectClass().toString() == Pedestrian.class.getSimpleName())
        // add element to Pedestrian ArrayList
}
```

Comment: Please show the full use-case of why you need this

Comment: Also, there is [Get generic type of java.util.List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list)

Comment: @4castle thank you, the link helped me.

Comment: Why don't you just just overload `handleEntities` for each subclass of `Entity`? That would make your code more extensible.

Comment: @4castle yes it would, but I don't feel like writing boilerplate over a simple case of if-else. Also, In a future, I could need to create more classes extending Entity, I'm not sure this would be a nice investment.

Comment: Okay, but considering what you want to do is impossible, it's not like you have a choice. Plus, it would actually be very easy to extend in the future. Put all of the boilerplate in another method that handles any `List<Entity>`, and then put specific subclass implementations in the overload.

Comment: Alternatlively you could extend the array list to be a typed subtype and distinct list not byt the object it is containing but by the type of the list itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is literally impossible, if the list is empty.

Read up on erasure for details.

Answer (score 0):

For a class defined with generics such as :

```
class <T> myClass
```

Within the constructor you can define a class classType reference you can then use with instanceOf, .getClass() etc when holding the ArrayList.

```
try {
    classType = (Class<T>)
                ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
                        .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
} catch (ClassCastException cce) {
        classType = (Class<T>) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
}
```

A simpler approach may to have the BaseClass define a Class getClassRef() that returns either Biker.class or Pedestrian.class as a result.

Comment: Nice approach, though I was looking for something simpler since it's a very "soft" case. Thank you by the way

Comment: This doesn't work unless you have a concrete subclass.