# How to get Model Data type of ArrayList in Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

Following onFilter() method is giving me an array list, but I've different arraylist with different models, 
e.g: ArrayList, ArrayList etc .

```
  @Override
public void onFilter(ArrayList items) {
    if (items != null && items.size() > 0) {
        if (items.get(0) instanceof ChatModel) {
            // Do something
        } else if (items.get(0) instanceof ContactDetailModel) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

Here I can easily check the type of Array Object, but how can I check arraylist model type if array is empty? Can we check whole arraylist model type without getting its object?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I check arraylist model type if array is empty?

Simply, you can't as there is no extra type information whatsoever in the ArrayList. It is only `Object`s.

> Can we check whole arraylist model type without getting its object?

`ArrayList` only holds elements of type `Object`. So checking the first element does not guarantee that whole array is of that type. Although there is a **compile-time** checking (ArrayList<>), at runtime you have to iterate over all the elements and check with `instanceof` to ensure that they are of the type that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Java `Reflection`.

There is an example:

```
public class Test {

    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Field stringListField = Test.class.getDeclaredField("stringList");
        ParameterizedType stringListType = (ParameterizedType) stringListField.getGenericType();
        Class<?> stringListClass = (Class<?>) stringListType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        System.out.println(stringListClass); // class java.lang.String.

        Field integerListField = Test.class.getDeclaredField("integerList");
        ParameterizedType integerListType = (ParameterizedType) integerListField.getGenericType();
        Class<?> integerListClass = (Class<?>) integerListType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        System.out.println(integerListClass); // class java.lang.Integer.
    }
}
```

In your case your will need to get the type of a function parameter. In this case `Reflection` can be user by the same way, at your parameter, using:

```
public void onFilter(ArrayList items) {

    // using
    items.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();

    // or
    ((ParameterizedType) items
        .getClass()
        .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
}
```

By this way, your `ArrayList` do not need to has any item.

Without that, **is not possible to get the relative generic type in runtime**, because of the data type erasure at compile time of generics.

[Link to related awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1942680/8405762)

Comment: Did Not understood why. Could you please develop your comment @OrkhanAlikhanov?

Comment: You are not totally right. My original solution is an example of a variable in `Heap` list. But you can use reflection in a variable in `Stack` list with a very similar way. I update my answer with that solution

Comment: Try it in Java 8