# Get actual type of generic wildcard collection at run-time

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Given:

```
public void methodOne() {
    List<RuntimeException> list = new ArrayList<RuntimeException>();
    methodTwo(list);
}

public void methodTwo(List<? extends Exception> list) {

}
```

Is there any way to check the actual type of the list in *methodTwo* at run-time? 
I know there is similar question
[Get generic type of java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list)
however my question is specifically about wildcards.

Please note that the collection might be empty so checking the elements might not work.

Comment: If you meant getting the type of the `List`, I don't think that's possible at run-time.

Comment: Yes, a range is allowed but the actual type is specific - in this case it's RuntimeException.

Comment: Generics are erased at runtime. As far as the runtime is concerned, `new ArrayList<RuntimeException>();` looks the same as `new ArrayList<IllegalArgumentException>();` You physically cannot determine this at runtime.

Comment: ...but if you tell us why you think you need this, we might be able to help you solve your problem in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the type at runtime due to type erasure.

The type is not stored and instead converted to either object for unbound parameters or the first bound class for bound parameters. Reference:  [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)