# How to get the class name generic interface

Tags: java, spring

```
public interface Transformer<I, O> {
    O transform(I var1);
}

class Test{
  @Autowired
  // The purpose of this transformer is to convert java object to 
  ion formatted string
  private Transformer<Car,String> serialize;

  public void fun(){
   Car c = new Car();
   c.setName("Audi");
   String ion = serialize.transform(c);
  }
}
```

Transformer interface is getting implemented by some class containing the logic for transformation . I need to know the class name of the generic params passed in while initialising the variable.

Comment: Hey! What *exactly* is your question or problem?

Comment: If your *variable* is class field you may be interested in [Get generic type of java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1942644)

Comment: updated the question for better understandibility