# Get generic type of java.util.List<java.util.List<E>>

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have:

```java
class TestClass {
  public List<Integer> integerList;
  public List<String> stringList;
  public List<List<String>> listOfStringLists;
  public List<List<Integer>> listOfIntegerLists;
}
```

The reflection-based proposed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1942680) works well to get the generic parameter type of `integerList` (ie. `Integer`) or of `stringList` (ie. `String`).

Is there a similarly easy way to retrieve the generic parameters for `listOfStringLists` and `listOfIntegerLists`?

**Edit:** based on @Pshemo suggestion casting the second cast not to `Class<?>` but to `ParameterizedType` did the trick:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.List;

public class TestClass {
    public List<Integer> integerList;
    public List<List<String>> listOfStringLists;

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Field integerListField = TestClass.class.getDeclaredField("integerList");
        ParameterizedType integerListType = (ParameterizedType) integerListField.getGenericType();
        Class<?> integerListClass = (Class<?>) integerListType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        System.out.println(integerListClass); // class java.lang.Integer.

        Field listOfListsField = TestClass.class.getDeclaredField("listOfStringLists");
        ParameterizedType listOfListsType = (ParameterizedType) listOfListsField.getGenericType();
        ParameterizedType listOfListsTypeParameter = (ParameterizedType) listOfListsType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]; // N.B. this cast to 'ParameterizedType' (not Class<?>) is important
        Class<?> listOfListsTypeParameterClass = (Class<?>) listOfListsTypeParameter.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        System.out.println(listOfListsTypeParameterClass); // class java.lang.String.
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, you extract the generic type parameter twice instead of once.

Comment: `field.getGenericType()` will give you `List<List<String>>` which is `ParameterizedType`. Use `getActualTypeArguments()[0]` on it to get `List<String>` but **don't cast it to** `(Class<?>)`, it is for non-generic types. Instead cast it to `(ParameterizedType)` so you could again use `getActualTypeArguments()[0]` on it to get`String` which then can be cast to `Class<?>` if you want.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks for the hint!