# By using a string like 'List<String>', how can I get its class, just like classForName("List<String>")?

Tags: java, list, reflect

I want to execute a method by using reflect, the method has a parameter which is a `List` type, and the list type is not stable, maybe `List《String》`, `List《someClass》`. ect.

Comment: You may find the answer at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: so what I acutally want to do is that, by receiving a method of a string like 'xxxpackage.xxxclass.xxxmethod(List<xxxClass> a)'，then I want to execute the method by using reflect,however,I don't know how to deal with the 'List<xxxClass>'? the generic type is not stable, I had deal with simple params such as 'int,string,' or custom entity class and their array,but I can't deal with their List type