# Jackson TypeReference with dynamic method parameter type

Tags: java, reflection, jackson

I want to be able to create Jackson TypeReference with dynamic method parameter type with below example using reflection  method.getParameterTypes()[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list).

Since  TypeReference only takes compile type parameters but I read in SO you can do some trick to let it also to work with dynamic types.

```
 Method method = methodsMap.getOrDefault("createXXX".toLowerCase(), null);

    if(method != null && myBean!= null){           
        Object retval = method.invoke(myBean, mapper.convertValue(product , new TypeReference<method.getParameterTypes()[0]>(){}));
    }
```

where method.getParameterTypes()[0] is of type of java [util generic list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list) (the type erasure issue)

> `List<MyPojo>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `getParameterTypes` at all. You should use `getGenericParameterTypes`, to get a `Type` instead. You can then pass that `Type` to a [`TypeFactory`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html#constructType(java.lang.reflect.Type)) to get a `JavaType`, which [`convertValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue(java.lang.Object,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType)) also accepts.

```
Type parameterType = method.getGenericParameterTypes()[0];
method.invoke(myBean, mapper.convertValue(
        product, 
        mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(parameterType)
    )
);
```

Comment: method.getGenericParameterTypes()[0] is of List<Product>

Comment: @TalAvissar And your point is...?

Comment: I would like to know if the example you showed above will work also for void foo(String param1, List<Product> lst);   compared to   <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c)

Comment: It wouldn't work on either of those methods, because they take 2 parameters, but you are calling them with only one parameter using `invoke`. Maybe you have not explained your situation clearly enough, or you do not actually know what you are doing at all...

Comment: @TalAvissar If we remove `String param1` and `T[] a` though, then this will work for the former method, but not the latter, because the latter's parameter type has a type variable, and you can't convert JSON to a type that has type variables in it. But it seems like you have an array here. If you know the `Class` of the array, it is possible to construct a type without type variables, to which you can convert the JSON.

Comment: @TalAvissar If you want to know how to call `fromArrayToCollection` with reflection, that could be asked as another question.