# Why doesn't Java erase types in an inheritance chain?

Tags: java, type-erasure

Type erasure only seems to occur when instantiating a generic type, but if you extend a generic type and provide a concrete type in place of `T`, the type is available at runtime. It seems to be the only time that the type isn't erased.

In the following example, `String` will be erased:

```java
List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
```

In the following example, as the implementation is still generic, any usage of it will erase whatever is in place of `T`.

```java
public final class ArrayList<T> implements List<T> { ... }
```

But, the moment the implementation is no longer generic, where `T` has been replaced by a concrete type in the inheritance chain, it's discoverable via reflection.

```java
public final class IntegerList implements List<Integer> { ... }
```

Why doesn't the type get erased when implemented via inheritance?

Comment: "*..but if you extend a generic type and provide a concrete type in place of T, the type is available at runtime. It seems to be the only time that the type isn't erased.*" not *only*, if `List<Integer>` would be for instance class field, or method parameter or method return type we could also read it at runtime. Related: [Get generic type of java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1942644)

Comment: "*Why doesn't the type get erased when implemented via inheritance?*" Simple answer: because reified types are good. The better question is why they didn't do it *more*, not less. The answer to that is: compatibility reasons.

Comment: Why? Because that information must be saved in the classfile, otherwise the compiler would need the source code if that class is used somewhere else (e.g. when compiling `List<String> example = new IntegerList()` in a third class and only having no source for `IntegerList` [just from a JAR file?] ) or it would not be possible to check if the assignment is valid (at compile time)

Comment: Your `IntegerList` is not generic. Broadly speaking there is no type to erase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, the moment the implementation is no longer generic ...

That's the answer. Type erasure occurs for generic types. The subclass `IntegerList` is not generic. Non-generic types are reifiable, which means that the types are available at runtime.

From the [Java Language Specification, 4.7: Reifiable Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7):

> 4.7 Reifiable Types
>
> Because some type information is erased during compilation, not all types are available at run time. Types that are
> completely available at run time are known as reifiable types.
>
> A type is reifiable if and only if one of the following holds:
>
> • It refers to a non-generic class or interface type declaration.
>
> ...