# Java enums in generic type

Tags: java, generics, enums

I'd like to create a generic enum-based mapper for IBatis. I'm doing this with the below code. This does have compile time errors, which I don't know how to fix. Maybe my solution is just plain wrong (keep in mind the use of IBatis), in such case please suggest something better.

Any help appreciated.

What I want to achieve is to define subsequent mappers as:

```
public class XEnumTypeHandler extends CommonEnumTypeHandler<X> {
}
```

The current code:

```
public class CommonEnumTypeHandler<T extends Enum> implements TypeHandlerCallback {

 public void setParameter(ParameterSetter ps, Object o) throws SQLException {
  if (o.getClass().isAssignableFrom(**T**)) { 
   ps.setString(((**T**) o).value().toUpperCase());
  } else
   throw new SQLException("Excpected ParameterType object than: " + o);
 }

 public Object getResult(ResultGetter rs) throws SQLException {
  Object o = valueOf(rs.getString());
  if (o == null)
   throw new SQLException("Unknown parameter type: " + rs.getString());
  return o;
 }

 public Object valueOf(String s) {
  for (T pt : T.**values()**) {
   if (pt.**value()**.equalsIgnoreCase(s))
    return pt;
  }
  return null;
 }
}
```

I've added error markings to the above code, the error messages are in order:

- T cannot be resolved
- The method value() is undefined for
  the type T
- The method values() is undefined for
  the type T
- The method values() is undefined for
  the type T

I've solved this issue with the following code:

```
public class CommonEnumTypeHandler<T extends Enum> implements TypeHandlerCallback {

    Class<T> clazz;

    public CommonEnumTypeHandler(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void setParameter(ParameterSetter ps, Object o) throws SQLException {
        if (o.getClass().isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            ps.setString(((T) o).name().toUpperCase());
        } else
            throw new SQLException("Excpected " + clazz + " object than: " + o);
    }

    public Object getResult(ResultGetter rs) throws SQLException {
        Object o = valueOf(rs.getString());
        if (o == null)
            throw new SQLException("Unknown parameter type: " + rs.getString());
        return o;
    }

    public Object valueOf(String s) {
        return Enum.valueOf(clazz, s);
    }
}
```

Inheriting from this class I do:

```
public class SalesChannelTypeHandler extends CommonEnumTypeHandler<SalesChannel> {

    public SalesChannelTypeHandler() {
        super(SalesChannel.class);
    }

    public SalesChannelTypeHandler(Class<SalesChannel> clazz) {
        super(clazz);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add the compiler errors and some description of what you're actually trying to achieve

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing (a general overview in words would be nice), but:

- You can't do `isAssignableFrom(T)` (you need a `Class` object), and you can't do `instanceof T` either (generics are non-reified). You *may* want to pass `Class<T>` type tokens instead.
- Have you looked at [`EnumMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html)?

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Runtime Type Tokens](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html)
- [Neal Gafter's Blog - Super Type Tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html)
- [Josh Bloch - Typesafe Heterogenous Container (THC) pattern (PDF)](http://developers.sun.com/learning/javaoneonline/2006/coreplatform/TS-1512.pdf)

---

It's still not clear what is desired, but perhaps it's something along the lines of this:

```
enum Color { BLACK, WHITE; }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Color c = Enum.valueOf(Color.class, "black".toUpperCase());
    System.out.println(c); // prints "BLACK"
}
```

So we use [`Enum.valueOf`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) that takes a type token `Class<T extends Enum<T>>`, and ask it for the `enum` constant with a given name. `valueOf` is *NOT* case-insensitive, but by conventions, *all* constants should be in uppercase, so we simply take the query string and turn it `.toUpperCase()`.

Comment: @Marcin: again, you can't do `T.values()`, but if you pass the type token for `Class<T>`, you'd be able to. I'll give an example, but I'm still not sure what you're doing.

Comment: Just trying to write a generic "from string to enum of defined type" converter. You pass in a string, say "test" and get enum TestEnum.test

Comment: @Marcin: I understand what you're trying to achieve, but face it: [Generics are not reified in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927789/why-should-i-care-that-java-doesnt-have-reified-generics)! You need to pass it as runtime method argument instead of as compiletime generic type. Maybe a constructor is useful?

Comment: @Marcin: so you want a case-insensitive Enum.valueOf? http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: @BalusC Ok, I understand now, but I'm not sure what do you mean by passing Class<T> token. Could You show me some examples of that usage?

Comment: @Marcin: essentially you pass instances of `Class` objects around. You either get this with the `.class` literal, or `Class.forName`, or `something.getClass()`, etc. These objects exist at run-time, so they can be used to support generics type system (which are non-reified).

Answer (score 4):

As pointed by Polygenelubricants, you need to pass concrete runtime types around, e.g. `Class<?>` instead of syntactic compiletime types like generic parameters. Here's a rewrite how you could use it:

```
public abstract class CommonEnumTypeHandler<E extends Enum<E>> implements TypeHandlerCallback {
    private Class<E> enumClass;

    public CommonEnumTypeHandler(Class<E> enumClass) {
        this.enumClass = enumClass;
    }

    public void setParameter(ParameterSetter ps, Object o) throws SQLException {
        if (enumClass.isInstance(o)) {
            ps.setString((enumClass.cast(o)).name().toUpperCase());
        } else {
            throw new SQLException("Excpected ParameterType object than: " + o);
        }
    }

    public Object getResult(ResultGetter rs) throws SQLException {
        try {
            return Enum.valueOf(enumClass, rs.getString());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new SQLException("Unknown parameter type: " + rs.getString(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Which you can then use as follows:

```
public class XEnumTypeHandler extends CommonEnumTypeHandler<X> {
    public XEnumTypeHandler() {
        super(X.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still not sure what OP wants, but I'll upvote this anyway. I'm sure you're correct =)

Comment: In `setParameter`, change `isAssignableFrom` to `enumClass.isInstance( o )`

Comment: @poly: He wants a generic enum <--> string converter for an object relational mapper. Java enum types aren't supported in JDBC. @Alex: updated!

Comment: @BalusC: whatever skill allowed you to know that, I want to learn it.

Comment: @poly: [learn JDBC](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) and [DAO](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) and try to refactor everything away and still keep it cross-DB-compatible. In other words: reinvent [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org) / [iBATIS](http://ibatis.apache.org/) / [JPA](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html) ;)

Comment: @polygenelubricants. Long usability meetings with customers.  I arrived to similar solutions but Balus beat me by a few seconds.