# Java : How I can get the type of the generic type at runtime

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Get generic type of class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime)
>   [How to get the generic type at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941384/how-to-get-the-generic-type-at-runtime)

Hi there,

How I can get the type for a generic type in java at runtime?

In C# I can use the `typeof` operator. With the `typeof` operator I get a type object with further information about the type of this generic type at runtime.

Is there a equivalent operator in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards, patrick

//Edit :

What I want to do :

```
public ArrayList<T> SelectObjects() {

            // I need to get here the type name for the oql script! 
    //this.SelectObjects( "select p from " + Class.forName(T));


}

public ArrayList<T> SelectObjects(String oql) {

     try {
            Iterator<T> iterator =
                   this.em.createQuery(oql).getResultList().iterator();

            ArrayList<T> objects = 
                new ArrayList<T>();

            while(iterator.hasNext())
            {
                objects.add(iterator.next());
            }

            return objects;
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
         }
}
```

I set up an oql script dynamically. How can I get the type from T?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getClass()` on the object instance.

```
public void someMethod(T instance) {

    if ( instance != null ) {
        System.out.println("Instance type: " + instance.getClass();
    }

}
```

You can use reflection to obtain more information about the retrieved class.

Comment: Hi JVerstry, Thanks for your answer. But my problem is, that I haven't an instance as parameter. In C# I can do typeof(T) and I get the whole type information.

Comment: In this case, there is NO other option but to pass a Class<T> parameters in your function and obtain type information from it.