# Java override constructor using List<CustomObjects> - "same erasure" error

Tags: java, generics

Hi I want to override constructor in custom class MyList.

Code below can be compiled, I receive "same erasure" error. For compiler `List<CustomClass1>` is same type as `List<CustomClass2>`

Can someone suggest me how to solve this. I try using `List<Object>` and using `instanceof` but I can't solve this but without success

```
private static class MyList {

    private int type;

    public MyList (List<CustomClass1> custom1) {
                 type = 1;
    }

    public MyList (List<CustomClass2> custom2) {
                 type = 2;

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method has the same erasure as another method in type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998544/method-has-the-same-erasure-as-another-method-in-type)

Answer (score 1):

Because of what is called **type erasure** [the generic type information is lost during compilation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Both compile down to `public MyList(List l)` when the type information is erased. This is just how Java works. Generics are only available during compile time.

> When a generic type is instantiated, the compiler translates those
>   types by a technique called type erasure — a process where the
>   compiler removes all information related to type parameters and type
>   arguments within a class or method. Type erasure enables Java
>   applications that use generics to maintain binary compatibility with
>   Java libraries and applications that were created before generics.

Answer (score 1):

The java compiler "erases" the type parameter. So `List<CustomClass1>` and `List<CustomClass2>` becomes `List` after the type erasure (de facto the same signature):

```
public MyList (List list) {
    // ...
}
```

You could add the type as parameter:

```
public MyList (List<?> list, int type) {
    // ...
}
```

or maybe

```
public MyList (List<?> list, Class<?> clazz) {
    // ...
}
```

or add type parameter to class

```
class MyList<T> {

    public MyList (List<T> custom2, Class<T> clazz) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx for your answer, but how can I check list type(`CustomClass1` or `CustomClass2`)? I try using  ` if (list.getClass().equals(CustomClass1.class)) {` but this not work

Comment: @Jovan: if you pass the `Class` as parameter you could add a method `getClazz()` that returns this value and use `list.getClazz().equals(CustomClass1.class)` almost as usual

Comment: @Jovan: maybe interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624113/get-type-name-for-generic-parameter-of-generic-class