# Java method overload - ambiguity

Tags: java, overloading, javac

While I was doing some runs to test some code in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377949/duplicate-method-while-method-overloading) I found out a strange thing, If you consider the following program

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class OverloadTest {

    public String test1(List l){
        return "abc";
    }

    public int test1(List<Integer> l){
        return 1;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        List l = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println(new OverloadTest().test1(l));
    }
}
```

I was expecting Java compiler to show **ambiguity error** due to byte-code Erasure property, but it didn't. Now when I tried to run this code, I was expecting that `test1(List)` will be called and the output would be `"abc"` but to my surprise it called `test1(List<Integer>)` (output was `1`)

I even tried like below

```
List l = new ArrayList();
l.add("a");
System.out.println(new OverloadTest().test1(l));
```

But still found Java calling `test1(List<Integer> param)` method and when i inspected the `param` it had the `String` "a" ( how did Java cast `List<String>` to `List<Integer>` ?)

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't compile at all for me - I get an error of: `error: name clash: test1(List<Integer>) and test1(List) have the same erasure`

Comment: Same here, in java templated data structures are related so it should not compile, however if you use c++ something similar to this may compile as templated classes don't share anything

Comment: I have the code complied in Eclipse Indigo, Java 1.6.0_30

Comment: @sanbhat Have you tried compiling with `javac`? Maybe there's a bug in Eclipse's compiler.

Comment: `javac` is giving me the ambiguity error!!  how could Eclipse Indigo compile and even run this piece of code??

Comment: @sanbhat because the Eclipse compiler had a bug, evidently.

Comment: Thanks @Antimony for pointers, this avoided by confusion

Comment: I don't get this error in Juno Service Release 1, Java 1.7_11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fixed bug. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=354229

It looks like this bug existed in javac5, javac6 and ecj for Eclipse 3.7, but it was fixed in Eclipse 3.8 and later.