# How to get the class of a field of type T?

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-mvc

I write JUnit tests for some Spring MVC Controllers. The initialization of the JUnit test is common for all my Controllers tests, so I wanted to create an abstract class that does this initialization.

Thus, I created the following code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:spring/applicationContext-test.xml", "classpath*:spring/spring-mvc-test.xml" })
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractSpringMVCControllerTest<T> {

    @Autowired
    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    protected MockHttpServletRequest request;

    protected MockHttpServletResponse response;

    protected HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;

    protected T controller;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Before
    public void initContext() throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException {
        request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        handlerAdapter = applicationContext.getBean(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.class);
        // Does not work, the problem is here...    
        controller = applicationContext.getBean(T);
    }

}
```

The idea is to create, for each controller I want to test a JUnit test class that extends my `AbstractSpringMVCControllerTest`. The type given in the `extends` declaration is the class of the **Controller**.

For example, if I want to test my `AccountController`, I will create the `AccountControllerTest` class like that:

```
public class AccountControllerTest extends AbstractSpringMVCControllerTest<AccountController> {

    @Test
    public void list_accounts() throws Exception {
        request.setRequestURI("/account/list.html");
        ModelAndView mav = handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, controller);
        ...
    }

}
```

My problem is located in the last line of the `initContext()` method of the abstract class. This abstract class declares the `controller` object as a `T` object, but how can say to the Spring Application Context to return the bean of type `T`?

I've tried something like that:

```
    Class<?> controllerClass = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("controller").getType();
    controller = (T) applicationContext.getBean(controllerClass);
```

but `controllerClass` returns the `java.lang.Object.class` class, not `AccountController.class`.

Of course, I can create a `public abstract Class<?> getControllerClass();` method, which will be overriden by each JUnit Controller test class, but I prefer to avoid this solution.

So, any idea?

Comment: If you have a better idea for the question title, do not hesitate :)

Comment: Welcome to the java type erasure nightmare.

Comment: It's impossible. Duplicate of [Get type name for generic parameter of generic class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624113/get-type-name-for-generic-parameter-of-generic-class)

Comment: Yeah indeed, I totally forgot that I encounter (again) this type erasure.

Comment: Does `controller = (T) applicationContext.getBean(T);` (or `T.class` in that second part, been a while since I've worked with Java) not work? I'm guessing not, if it's a runtime thing.... Actually, now that I think about it, when I encountered a similar issue, I ended up doing something pretty similar to your `public abstract Class<?> getControllerClass();` solution, though what I did was store the class names as strings and use `Class.forName()` to get the classes.

Comment: @JAB Indeed, it does not compile.

Comment: well. this is a litter different, this is a parameter in supertype. See my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible *if* your subclasses of `AbstractSpringMVCControllerTest` bind `T` at compile time.  That is, you have something like

```
public class DerpControllerTest extends AbstractSpringMVCControllerTest<DerpController> { }
```

rather than

```
public class AnyControllerTest<T> extends AbstractSpringMVCControllerTest<T> { }
```

I'm guessing you probably have the former.  In this case, the type of `T` is erased from the `Class` object for `AbstractSpringMVCControllerTest` at runtime, but the `Class` object for `DerpControllerTest` *does* provide a way to know what `T` is, since it bound `T` at compile time.

The following classes demonstrate how to access the type of `T`:

**Super.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
public abstract class Super<T> {

    protected T object;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Class<T> getObjectType() {
        // This only works if the subclass directly subclasses this class
        return (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

}
```

**Sub.java**

```
public class Sub extends Super<Double> {
}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        Sub s = new Sub();
        System.out.println(s.getObjectType()); // prints "Class java.lang.Double"
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize you could get at generic class parameters like this. Even if the test class doesn't directly subclass the generic superclass, I'm sure you could write some code to walk to the class hierarchy and get at the class or interface you're after.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely possible, but I didn't want to get into that, because handling `Sub<T> extends Super<T>; SubSub extends Sub<Double>` would be different than `Sub extends Super<T>; SubSub extends Sub`.  And that still doesn't address the possibility of introducing other generic parameters, like `Sub<S, T> extends Super<T>; SubSub<S> extends Sub<S, Double>`.

Answer (score 3):

This is different from the type erasure we normally see. With type erasure, we don't know the parameter of the current class (the one you get with `getClass()`), but you can get those in super class / super interface (those you get with `getGenericSuperxxxxx()`) because this is part of the type declaration.

This won't give your the type of `controller` field, but I hope this is enough for your purpose.

Code:

```
public class A<P> {
}

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;

public class B extends A<String> {

    public  static void main(String[] arg) {
        System.out.println(
                ((ParameterizedType)B.class.getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
class java.lang.String
```

In your case, it would be

```
Class controllerClass = (Class)( ((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
```

Something to notes:

If the class `B` is also parameterized like this:

```
public class B<X> extends A<X> {}
```

This won't work. Or if you have another class extends B, it will have problem too. I won't go into all those cases, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Man, reflection is awesome, but I hate how Java implements it. Guess that's what happens when you implement reflection for a language that didn't originally support it and wasn't designed with reflection in mind. ...Then again there are quite a few things I don't like about the way Java's standard library is set up, so that might be the problem to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You can't because at runtime, due to ERASURE, the JVM cannot know the class of your "controller" attribute. It is considered as Object...