# Get .class Object of Generic Class

Tags: java, generics

I am tying to save the Type of a generic value, because i can't get it at runtime:

```java
public class A<T> {
    private final Class<T> genericType;
    public A(Class<T> genericType) {
        this.genericType = genericType;
    }

    public Class getGenericType() {
        return genericType;
    }
}
```

To make subclasses now, I use it as follows:

```
public class B extends A<String> {
    public B() {
        super(String.class);
    }
}
```

Note thet the super()'s parameter type matches (by compile timne check) to the A's generic type.
That works fine. But if i want to have it with a Map, i cannot get the correct class object:

```
public class C extends A<Map<String, String>> {
    public C() {
        super(Map.class); // does not match Map<String,String>
        super(Map<String,String>.class) // no valid java expression, i dont know what 
    }
}
```

Sooo anyone got a tip to help me out of this misery?
Best i could do currently, is to give up the strong typing in A:

```
public class A<T> {
    // old: private final Class<T> genericType;
    private final Class genericType;  // note the missing generic
    public A(Class genericType) {     // here as well
        this.genericType = genericType;
    }

    public Class getGenericType() {
        return genericType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally it's tricky to pass generic types around like that. Maybe take a look at Jackson for inspiration, wherein you anonymously extend TypeReference with your actual typing, which allows retaining type information

Comment: Guava uses the same pattern for `TypeToken`, which is intended to be used in general code.

Comment: thx for your suggestions :) so far, it seems like a rabbit hole that i wanted to avoid for my (except this case) simple code. Guava and Jackson seem to have a quite similar way of dealing with it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether this satisfied your requirement, but you can do something similar as bellow, see [How to get the class of a field of type T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158912/how-to-get-the-class-of-a-field-of-type-t)

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;


public class GenericTypeTest{

     public static void main(String []args){
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println("B is a " + b.getGenericType());
        C c = new C();
        System.out.println("C is a " + c.getGenericType());
     }
}


class A<T> {
      public Class getGenericType() {
          Object genericType =  ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
           if(genericType instanceof ParameterizedType){
               genericType = ((ParameterizedType)genericType).getRawType();
           }
        return (Class<T>) genericType;
    }
}



class B extends A<String> {
}

class C extends A<Map<String,String>> {
}
```

this will get output something like

```
B is a class java.lang.String
C is a interface java.util.Map
```

Answer (score 0):

There is just one `Class` object representing `Map` at runtime, which you can get by evaluating `Map.class`. There are no separate `Class` objects representing `Map<String, String>` or `Map<Integer, Integer>` or whatever at runtime. If you just want to take `Map.class`, which normally has type `Class<Map>`, and force that into `Class<Map<String, String>>`, you could do that via some unchecked casts:

```
super((Class<Map<String, String>>)(Class<?>)Map.class);
```

But whether that would do what you want depends on what you expect to do with your variable of type `Class<T>`, `genericType`, which you have not shown. For example, if you will use its `.isInstance()` method to check whether an object is an instance of `T` at runtime, know that since we don't know the generic type arguments of objects at runtime, we will only be able to check the raw type of the object, and not its type argument. This is the same reason why you can do `foo instanceof Map` or `foo instanceof Map<?>` but not `foo instanceof Map<String, String>`.

Or, maybe you want to use its `.cast()` method to do a type check on an object at runtime, which normally throws an exception if the object is not an instance of the `Class`'s class, and if it is, it returns the object, but with compile-time type `T`. But here, again, you can't check at runtime whether an object is an instance of a parameterized type like `Map<String, String>`; you can only check whether it is a `Map`. So by it allowing you to get the result as type `T` without warning might be unsafe, as you get a compile-time expression of type `Map<String, String>`, but it might really be a `Map<Integer, Integer>`. This is the same reason why an unchecked cast like `(Map<String, String>)foo` causes an unchecked cast warning. It is unsafe and might cause unexpected problems elsewhere in your code.