# Java reflection: how to get the class of a method's generic type?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to code a generic method, whic given just the `Type` as input is able to access the corresponding class.
Note that no parameter is passed to the method (as already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54044100/java-getting-the-name-of-generic-class)), but just the type is specified.

Here is the corresponding code:

```
@Bean
public <T> ConsumerFactory <String, T> consumerFactory() {
 Class <T> genericClass = null; //How to get the class corresponding to type T ? 

 return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(),
  new StringDeserializer(),
  new JsonDeserializer<>(genericClass, objectMapper)
 );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should introduce a type token as a method parameter. You won't be able get `T` information as it's erased during compilation.

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> newStringConsumerFactory() {
  return newConsumerFactory(String.class);
}

private <T> ConsumerFactory <String, T> newConsumerFactory(Class<T> t) {
 return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(),
  new StringDeserializer(),
  new JsonDeserializer<>(t, objectMapper)
 );
}
```

You could try digging into reflection and [`Method.getGenericParameterTypes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericParameterTypes--) but it doesn't make the `@Configuration` readable. The verbosity and adhering to standards here is important as most IDEs are supporting Spring config and auto-wire hints