# Get Return Type of Method that Returns ArrayList<> via Reflection

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, reflection

I need to be able to retrieve the class/type of `Object` present in `ArrayList<TYPE>` returned by `Method method` via reflection.

When calling:

```
Class<?> methodReturnType = method.getReturnType();
System.out.println("Method return type: " + methodReturnType);
```

on a method that returns `ArrayList<String>` I get:

```
class java.util.ArrayList
```

which does not include information on the generic type: `String`.

I believe this question may have been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624113/get-type-name-for-generic-parameter-of-generic-class) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime) however I do see that if I call:

```
Type genericReturnType = method.getGenericReturnType();
System.out.println("Generic return type (name): " + genericReturnType.getTypeName());
```

This prints:

```
java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>
```

Which suggests that it is possible to know that the `ArrayList<>` holds `Object` of type `String`.

Obviously, I might be able to extract `String` from text: `<java.lang.String>` via regex but this is not ideal.

What am I missing? Is it possible to obtain the type of `ArrayList<>` of a method that returns `ArrayList<TYPE>` at run-time via reflection? If not, how does `genericReturnType.getTypeName()` print the right type (String)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list

Comment: @beastlyCoder works!  The  answer mainly describes solution when extracting type from `Field`. I now see the author states that this can also be applied to parameter types and return type of methods. This is what I missed. Thanks!

Comment: yay glad I could help!