# I have an api function that wants a Class<T> - how do I give it the class of a List<String>?

Tags: java

I'm using `List.class` because `List<String>.class` is wrong. Is there a syntax that gets the class of the parametrized class?

Code:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.camel.Message;
...
    Message m = exchange.getIn();
    List<String> serviceIds = null;
    serviceIds = m.getHeader("serviceId", List.class);
```

Of course I would rather have:

```
    serviceIds = m.getHeader("serviceId", List<String>.class);
```

to ensure that getHeader would return null if a list of something not strings was in the header.

Comment: I'm not sure this is clear enough. Can you precise the exact problem ? You want "T" from an instance of List<T> ?

Comment: Julian, can you provide perhaps a code snippet, or more detailed information about the API method, and how you want to use it?

Comment: you want to know what class is being used in the list ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot give it a class of `List<String>`, because there is no such class: the type of `<String>` is removed by the compiler during the process known as [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), leaving you with pure `List`.

Comment: Looks like I've got the best I can do. Not too impressed with Java here. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but if you have a `List` parameterized with some class, eg:

`List<Cat> myCats = new ArrayList<Cat>();`

And you have some API method that you want to call:

`public static void doSomething(Class<T> clazz);`

And you're looking to provide that method with `Cat.class`, there is unfortunately no way to determine (at runtime) the parameterized class that is being contained in the `List`. This information is erased at runtime.

I believe your question may be a duplicate of this one, but don't hesitate to correct me if I'm mistaken:

[How to get the generic type at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941384/how-to-get-the-generic-type-at-runtime)