# How can I access the the type of a generic object?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Looking at the Crud object code below, what I'm expecting is an array of Field objects for type T.  What I appear to actually get is an empty array of of Field objects for type Object.  My test class is called Timezone.  So, when I instantiate the Crud object it looks like...

```
Crud<Timezone> tz = new Crud<Timezone>();
```

But as I said this isn't working.  Help appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
public class Crud<T> {

    public T getInstance()
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T object = (T) new Object();
        return object;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMembers() {
        ArrayList<String> retval = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            T object = this.getInstance();
            Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields(); //Always empty
            for (Field field : fields) {
                retval.add(field.getName());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return retval;
    }

}
```

Comment: Of course they are `Object`s, you did `new Object();`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the generic type at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941384/how-to-get-the-generic-type-at-runtime)

Comment: That warning you are suppressing: it's useful here.

Answer (score 2):

Even without generics, you cannot do anything like this:

```
Timezone object = (Timezone) new Object();
```

`new Object()` will create an object whose *runtime type* is `Object`.  This will have all the fields and methods an `Object` has, but no others.  Once the `Object` is created, a cast cannot be used to magically convert the object to some other type; that would involve adding all the new fields and methods a `Timezone` has, and Java can't do that.

So this can't possibly work either:

```
T object = (T) new Object();
```

Unfortunately, Java won't let you do this either:

```
T object = new T();
```

because of "type erasure".  Please see [Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java) for some ideas for working around this (unless the solution without generics works for you).

Answer (score 2):

No, due to [*type erasure*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), you can't access the type at runtime.

However, there is a pattern to solve the problem of creating an instance of the generic type; you must pass a type *token* to the constructor:

```
public class Crud<T> {
    private Class<T> clazz;
    public Crud(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public T getInstance() {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is wrapping an instance and getting its fields, there's no need for generics. You can use `Object` as a base class to allow any kind of objects in your wrapper. For example

```
public class Crud {

    private final Object object;

    public Crud(final Object someObject) {
        this.object = someObject;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMembers() {
        ArrayList<String> retval = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            Field[] fields = this.object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : fields) {
                retval.add(field.getName());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return retval;
    }

}
```

Then you just do

```
Crud tz = new Crud(new Timezone());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably implement the method `getDeclaredFields()` specifically for Timezone, in class Timezone.

Comment: I don't really understand your answer. And no need to implement `getDeclaredFields()`, all `Class` objects have this method.

Answer (score 0):

We can define the generic class like so:

```
public class Crud<T> {

    private final Class<T> mClass;

    public Crud(Class<T> tClass)
    {
        mClass = tClass;
    }

    public T getInstance() throws Exception
    {
        T object = mClass.newInstance();
        return object;
    }

    ...
}
```

And then we can use it like this:

```
try
{
    Date tDate = new Crud<Date>(Date.class).getInstance();
    System.out.println("Date: " + tDate);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
}
```

Output: `Date: Mon Feb 24 21:00:04 PST 2014`

Comment: This is a Null Pointer Exception unless you initialize `tClass` to something.  When and how do you plan to initialize it?

Comment: @ajb You're totally right. I tested the new code and it should be fixed.