# Resolving a method's return type using its argument types

Tags: java, generics, reflection, guava

Suppose I have a method:

```
public class AwesomeClass {

    public <E> List<E> convertIterableToList(Iterable<E> iterable) {
        ...
    }

}
```

At *runtime*, how can I resolve the method's return type based on the argument type? For example, I wish to implement a hypothetical method `resolveReturnType` whose behavior is demonstrated in this little (pseudo-Java) unit test:

```
Method method = AwesomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("convertIterableToList", Iterable.class);

Type argumentType = {{{Set<String>}}}; // Just pretend this syntax works. :)
Type expectedReturnType = {{{List<String>}}};
Type actualReturnType = resolveReturnType(method, argumentType);

assertEquals(expectedReturnType, actualReturnType);
```

So far, I have been trying to use Guava's [TypeToken](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) class but I have been not making much progress.

Comment: Have you took a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941384/how-to-get-the-generic-type-at-runtime ? Also, when you know the parameter type and you can deduct the return from the parameter type, why would you want to check the return type again?

Comment: @Smutje: I took a lot at that question, but it does not appear to be addressing this problem. If I understand it correctly, they are trying to obtain generic information from an *object* at runtime. The code I provided is simply a unit test demonstrating what I am trying to accomplish. The actual production code will not know the expected return type. The production code will use `resolveReturnType` to tell it what a method's return type is, given its argument types.

Comment: Have you looked at the Javadoc for [`TypeToken.resolveType(Type)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html#resolveType(java.lang.reflect.Type)) ?

Comment: But, again - why would you re-calculate something that is already known?

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I have looked at `resolveType` and I have been hacking away at it for an evening, but I haven't been able to make it resolve the way I want it to. :(

Comment: @Smutje: Perhaps I am not making myself clear. You're right. Technically, we do already know the method's return type (`List<E>`). Sort of. However, *that* return type has a type variable (`E`). I want to know the method's return type with its type variable resolved to a *real* type (such as `List<String>` in my example). In reality, this method will not be used for such trivial cases, but I wanted something that would clearly demonstrate what I am trying to do.

Comment: If you knew `E` (e.g. in the form of `Type t`) then simply `TypeToken.of(t).resolveType(method.getGenericReturnType())` would do (or maybe `TypeToken.of(method.getGenericReturnType()).where(...)`). So all you need is to extract `E` from `List<E>` and there's `method.getgenericParameterTypes()`. Just put it together.

Comment: @Smutje It's not known if you do things like e.g. Gson does. When it serializes `List<Set<String>>` it must extract the `Set<String>` from its type argument so it know how to serialize the list members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is actually possible, provided that you have the actual formal `Type`s of the arguments to the method available. As @JvR notes, this isn't possible *in general* at runtime, but if (as in your example) you are able to explicitly specify those types using `TypeToken` or some such, it does work.

```
static Type resolveReturnType(Type classType, Method method, Type... argTypes) {
  // this should resolve any class-level type variables
  Type returnType = TypeToken.of(classType)
      .resolveType(method.getGenericReturnType()).getType();
  Type[] parameterTypes = method.getGenericParameterTypes();

  TypeResolver resolver = new TypeResolver();
  for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.length; i++) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // necessary for getSupertype call to compile
    TypeToken<Object> paramType =
        (TypeToken<Object>) TypeToken.of(parameterTypes[i]);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // necessary for getSupertype call to compile
    TypeToken<Object> argType =
        (TypeToken<Object>) TypeToken.of(argTypes[i]);

    if (method.isVarArgs() && i == parameterTypes.length - 1) {
      // TODO
    } else {
      TypeToken<?> argTypeAsParamType =
          argType.getSupertype(paramType.getRawType());
      resolver = resolver.where(
          paramType.getType(), argTypeAsParamType.getType());
    }
  }

  return resolver.resolveType(returnType);
}
```

There are some holes in the above code: for example, it won't resolve the return type of `E foo(E[] array)` correctly given an argument type of `String[]`. It also can't help with any generic method whose return type has a type variable that is not used in its parameter types, of course. I also haven't tried it with various other things, like wildcards. But for your example it works, and it also handles type variables declared by the class (if it's an instance method) in addition to those declared by the method:

```
public class Foo<T> {

  public <E> Map<T, E> convertIterableToMap(Iterable<E> iterable) {
    return null;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Method method = Foo.class.getMethod("convertIterableToMap", Iterable.class);

    Type instanceType = new TypeToken<Foo<Integer>>() {}.getType();
    Type setOfString = new TypeToken<Set<String>>() {}.getType();

    // prints: java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String>
    System.out.println(resolveReturnType(instanceType, method, setOfString));
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent and concise! I wish I could award bonus points for also resolving the instance type parameters. I was so fixated on the `TypeToken.resolveType` method that I completely overlooked its `getSuperclass` method.

Comment: One other thing this doesn't handle properly is the case where there are multiple instances of a type variable in the parameters: `TypeResolver` throws an exception when it tries to map the type variable to a real type a second time, even if the real type is the same both times. This could possibly be worked around by catching the `IllegalArgumentException` or (more annoyingly) by reimplementing `TypeResolver`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't.

Longer answer:

`<E> List<E> convertIterableToList(Iterable<E> iterable)` has a type `E` that is not generally reifiable.  You *could* check whether the supplied iterable has fixed this type <sup>(1)</sup> in its class definition, which means you could retrieve that and figure out what `E` means in that specific invocation.

But in the general case, the runtime won't know what `E` is for any specific invocation.

<sup>(1)</sup> <sub>Meaning something like `class StringList implements List<String>` where the type variable is fixed.</sub>