# Is there a way to avoid the constructor passing the Class?

Tags: java, generics

Consider this HashMap extention (generates an instance of the V class when calling "get" if it's null)

```
public class HashMapSafe<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V>{

    private Class<V> dataType;

    public HashMapSafe(Class<V> clazz){
        dataType = clazz;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        if(!containsKey(key)){
            try {
                put((K)key, dataType.newInstance());
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return super.get(key);
    }
}
```

The usage of it is something like this

```
Map<String,Section> sections = new HashMapSafe<String,Section>(Section.class);
sections.get(sectionName); //always returns a Section instance, existing or new
```

It seems to me redundant a little to supply "Section" twice, once as a generic type, and also supply it's class. I assume it's impossible, but is there to implement HashMapSafe, (keeping the same functionality) so it can be used like this?

```
Map<String,Section> sections = new HashMapSafe<String,Section>();
```

Or like this?:

```
Map<String,Section> sections = new HashMapSafe<String>(Section.class);
```

Comment: So, a google search for 'java newInstance generic class' turned up several old posts involving this.getClass() followed by an ability to access the generics of the object and therefore get the Class of those generics, suggesting your first option is possible.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java/75345#75345

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot improve the constructor usage due to type erasure as others have already pointed out, but you should be able to improve verbosity by using a static factory method instead of a constructor...

I am not in front of compiler and I can never get method type parameters right on first try, but it will go something like this...

```
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> create( Class<V> cl )
{
    return new HashMapSafe<K,V>(cl);
}

...

Map<String,Section> sections = HashMapSafe.create(Section.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. Java doesn't have [Reified generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927789/why-should-i-care-that-java-doesnt-have-reified-generics).

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has however a nice solution in flavor of [`MapMaker#makeComputingMap()`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#makeComputingMap%28com.google.common.base.Function%29)

```
Map<String, Integer> numbers = new MapMaker().makeComputingMap(new Function<String, Integer>() {
    public Integer apply(String key) {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Which sets and returns `0` instead of `null` when the key is not present (and it is threadsafe, as opposed to your solution).

Comment: That's a rather nice collection class :) I can imagine it being very useful as a cache without the normal effort.

Answer (score 1):

Neither are possible. The first would require being able to do something like `new V()` and that can't be done. The second would require being able to set the `V` type at runtime because it's passed in the constructor, which also can't be done. Keep in mind that generics are only used a compile time and they're erased for runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I found this article interesting: [Reflecting generics](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860)

in short using:

```
  public abstract class AbstractUserType<T> implements UserType {
    ...
    public Class returnedClass {
      ParameterizedType parameterizedType =
        (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperClass();
     return (Class) parameterizedtype.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Note that this only works when you declare a fixed generic type straight in the class like `class MyMap extends MyAbstractMap<String, Integer>`. I imagine that the OP would like to keep his class generic.

Comment: You can keep the class generic you just have you declare you class like this `new HashMapSafe<String,Section>() {}` note the extra `{}` You can make the class abstract to avoid forggeting to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to avoid the constructor passing the Class?

In short, No.

The root cause is "type erasure".  At runtime, the implementation of HashMapSafe has no implicit knowledge of the types that correspond to the type parameters.  That information is *erased*.  If you need the implementation to know what the type is, you need to pass it as a `Class` object that is compatible with `Class<V>`.

```
Map<String,Section> sections = new HashMapSafe<String,Section>();
```

That doesn't work because of type erasure; see above.

```
Map<String,Section> sections = new HashMapSafe<String>(Section.class);
```

That doesn't work because the Java language requires you to specify a type (or wildcard) for all of the type parameters when you use that syntax.