# Constraints in interface implementation in java

Tags: java, interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java generics constraint require default constructor like C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563654/java-generics-constraint-require-default-constructor-like-c-sharp)

I want to set a constraint to type T that it must have a constructor without parameters. In C# it will be like:

`public interface Interface<T> where T : new() { }`

Is this feature available in Java?

## Update: Is there some trick to make generic type T have a constructor?

Comment: Funny question in terms of java interface... Interface with constructor.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your updated question: only class can have a constructor in Java, T - is a type literal, it is not necessary has to be a class. During runtime using reflection you can check if your class is a [ParameterizedType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) has a parameter that is actually a class and if it has an empty constructor.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot define interface for constructors in Java. Nor you cann put any other constraints to type parameters, other than type variance.

Comment: **Misunderstanding** This defines constructor for generic type T and not the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this at compile time in Java.  I think that the best you can do is to try to verify this at runtime, by using reflection to do something like:

```
public static <T> boolean hasDefaultConstructor(Class<T> cls) {
    Constructor[] constructors = cls.getConstructors();
    for (Constructor constructor : constructors) {
        if (constructor.getParameterTypes().length == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then you can invoke this function by doing the following:

```
hasDefaultConstructor(String.class)  => true;
hasDefaultConstructor(Integer.class) => false;
```

If this function returns false, then you know the class will have no default constructor, and you can throw an exception or whatever is appropriate for your application.

Answer (score 0):

You could make T extend a class with the constructor you want

```
public interface Interface<T extends Constructable>{}

public abstract class Constructable{
    public Constructable(params..){
     }
}
```

Comment: But class inheriting Constructable may not have default constructor (without parameters).

Comment: of course it has, when inheriting you can not reduce the scope of the access modifier. If the parent class has a public constructor without parameters, then all the subclasses will have this constructor without parameters

Comment: Well, actually, this is not true. It has nothing to do with access modifiers. The set of constructors is unique for each particular class. You have to call one of the super-constructors in every constructor of a child class, unless parent has default constructor. Let's assume B is a sublcass of A. A has a default constructor. If you define only constructor B(String) in B, then you won't be able to instantiate B with just new B().

Comment: You are right, constructors are not inherited. Ups!!