# Trying to modify Java Vector's get() to make new T() if the element is null

Tags: java, vector, new-operator

I'm Trying to modify Java Vector to raise size if im accessing an element bigger than the vector's size. And to insert a new element if im accessing a not initialized element.

Eclipse throws cannot instantiate the type Obj.

```
public static class Vec<Obj> extends Vector<Obj> {
      @Override
      public Obj set(int a, Obj b) {
          if (super.size()<=a) super.setSize(a+1);
        return (Obj) super.set(a,b);
      }
      @Override
      public Obj get(int a) {
          if (super.size()<=a) super.setSize(a+1);
          if (super.get(a)==null) super.insertElementAt(  new Obj() , a);
        return (Obj) super.get(a);
      }
      public Vec () {
            super();  
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Obj` is a generic type; you cannot instantiate a generic type with `new`.

Comment: Relevant (but maybe outdated): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563654/java-generics-constraint-require-default-constructor-like-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that `T` has a no-args constructor. Also, people like to use interfaces, so there's a good chance `T` wont be concrete.

So, supply an *abstract factory* to the construction of your `Vec`. A suitable type is `java.util.function.Supplier<T>`.

```
  private final Supplier<T> dflt;
  public Vec(Supplier<T> dflt) {
      super(); 
      this.dflt = Objectes.requireNonNull(dflt); 
  }
  ...
           if (super.get(a)==null) {
               super.insertElementAt(dflt.get(), a);
           }
```

Construct as:

```
    Vec<Donkey> donkeys = new Vec<>(BigDonkey::new);
```

`java.util.Vector` methods should be `synchronized`, although such locking isn't really useful and `ArrayList` should generally be used instead. Even then, subclassing like this breaks LSP.